# Adding an identity to an existing column

Tags: sql, sql-server, alter-table, identity-column

I need to change the primary key of a table to an identity column, and there's already a number of rows in table.

I've got a script to clean up the IDs to ensure they're sequential starting at 1, works fine on my test database.

What's the SQL command to alter the column to have an identity property?

Answer (score 604, accepted):

You can't alter the existing columns for identity.

You have 2 options,

1. Create a new table with identity & drop the existing table
2. Create a new column with identity & drop the existing column

Approach 1. (*New table*) Here you can retain the existing data values on the newly created identity column. Note that you will lose all data if 'if not exists' is not satisfied, so make sure you put the condition on the drop as well!

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.Tmp_Names
    (
      Id int NOT NULL
             IDENTITY(1, 1),
      Name varchar(50) NULL
    )
ON  [PRIMARY]
go

SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Tmp_Names ON
go

IF EXISTS ( SELECT  *
            FROM    dbo.Names ) 
    INSERT  INTO dbo.Tmp_Names ( Id, Name )
            SELECT  Id,
                    Name
            FROM    dbo.Names TABLOCKX
go

SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Tmp_Names OFF
go

DROP TABLE dbo.Names
go

Exec sp_rename 'Tmp_Names', 'Names'
```

Approach 2 (*New column*) You can’t retain the existing data values on the newly created identity column, The identity column will hold the sequence of number.

```sql
Alter Table Names
Add Id_new Int Identity(1, 1)
Go

Alter Table Names Drop Column ID
Go

Exec sp_rename 'Names.Id_new', 'ID', 'Column'
```

See the following Microsoft SQL Server Forum post for more details:

[How to alter column to identity(1,1)](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/04d69ee6-d4f5-4f8f-a115-d89f7bcbc032)

Comment: If table data is small, this option works gret. If table is large, there's another option I prefer: use ALTER TABLE ... SWITCH to replace the table schema with another version with an IDENTITY column but otherwise identical schema. The advantage of the ALTER TABLE.... SWITCH approach is that it completes quickly (under 5 seconds for a billion-row table) since no table data needs to be copied or changed. There are caveats and limitations though. See my answer below for details.

Comment: @Justin Grat: A very interesting alternative and one that I had not considered! The reason this works is because IDENTITY is a column property and not a data type, so the SWITCH method validates the schemas between the two tables (old and new) as being identifiable irrespective of the IDENTITY difference. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: If you don't have much data, then "creating the table" can be achieved by generation a script from SSMS. Right click the table > Scrip Table as > Create TABLE to > (new query editor?). Then drop it, and inside that script you can add the `IDENTITY(1, 1)` part with the primary key column

Comment: One can also use SSMS to enforce this. Go to Tools > Options > Designers> Un-check "Prevent saving changes that require table re-creation". BTW this is not recommended for fairly large tables.

Comment: In PostgreSQL you *can* add identity to an existing integer column with the command: alter table {table_name} alter column {column_name} add generated always as identity (restart with {number});

Comment: Note that approach 2 will probably change the column order, so that your id, which was probably the leftmost column, is now the rightmost column. This shouldn't matter to any well-coded application, but it may break things if they're not coded so well, and it's disorientating when quickly selecting from a table to preview it.

Comment: I noticed that in SSMS you can change identity columns within the designer no problem. If you change or update a column identity within the designer, before saving you can click *'Generate Change Script'* and this code will be provided for you. The designer does the same temporary table trick behind the scenes.

Answer (score 260):

In SQL 2005 and above, there's a trick to solve this problem without changing the table's data pages. This is important for large tables where touching every data page can take minutes or hours.  The trick also works even if the identity column is a primary key, is part of a clustered or non-clustered index, or other gotchas which can trip up the the simpler "add/remove/rename column" solution.

Here's the trick: you can use SQL Server's [ALTER TABLE...SWITCH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-transact-sql) statement to change the schema of a table without changing the data, meaning you can replace a table with an IDENTITY with an identical table schema, but without an IDENTITY column.  The same trick works to add IDENTITY to an existing column.

Normally, [ALTER TABLE...SWITCH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-transact-sql) is used to efficiently replace a full partition in a partitioned table with a new, empty partition.  But it can also be used in non-partitioned tables too.

I've used this trick to convert, in under 5 seconds, a column of a 2.5 billion row table from IDENTITY to a non-IDENTITY (in order to run a multi-hour query whose query plan worked better for non-IDENTITY columns), and then restored the IDENTITY setting, again in less than 5 seconds.

Here's a code sample of how it works.

```
 CREATE TABLE Test
 (
   id int identity(1,1),
   somecolumn varchar(10)
 );
  
 INSERT INTO Test VALUES ('Hello');
 INSERT INTO Test VALUES ('World');
  
 -- copy the table. use same schema, but no identity
 CREATE TABLE Test2
 (
   id int NOT NULL,
   somecolumn varchar(10)
 );
  
 ALTER TABLE Test SWITCH TO Test2;

 -- drop the original (now empty) table
 DROP TABLE Test;

 -- rename new table to old table's name
 EXEC sp_rename 'Test2','Test';
  
 -- update the identity seed
 DBCC CHECKIDENT('Test');

 -- see same records
 SELECT * FROM Test;
```

This is obviously more involved than the solutions in other answers, but if your table is large this can be a real life-saver.  There are some caveats:

- As far as I know, identity is the only thing you can change about your table's columns with this method. Adding/removing columns, changing nullability, etc. isn't allowed.
- You'll need to drop foriegn keys before you do the switch and restore them after.
- Same for WITH SCHEMABINDING functions, views, etc.
- new table's indexes need to match exactly (same columns, same order, etc.)
- Old and new tables need to be on the same filegroup.
- Only works on SQL Server 2005 or later
- I previously believed that this trick only works on the Enterprise or Developer editions of SQL Server (because partitions are only supported in Enterprise and Developer versions), but Mason G. Zhwiti in his comment below says that it also works in SQL Standard Edition too.  I assume this means that the restriction to Enterprise or Developer doesn't apply to ALTER TABLE...SWITCH.

There's a good [article on TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191160.aspx) detailing the requirements above.

UPDATE - [Eric Wu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2713582/eric-wu) had a comment below that adds important info about this solution. Copying it here to make sure it gets more attention:

> There's another caveat here that is worth mentioning. Although the
> new table will happily receive data from the old table, and all the
> new rows will be inserted following a identity pattern, they will
> start at 1 and potentially break if the said column is a primary key.
> Consider running `DBCC CHECKIDENT('<newTableName>')` immediately after
> switching. See [msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057.aspx) for more
> info.

If the table is actively being extended with new rows (meaning you don't have much if any downtime between adding IDENTITY and adding new rows, then instead of `DBCC CHECKIDENT` you'll want to manually set the identity seed value in the new table schema to be larger than the largest existing ID in the table, e.g. `IDENTITY (2435457, 1)`. You might be able to include both the `ALTER TABLE...SWITCH` and the `DBCC CHECKIDENT` in a transaction (or not-- haven't tested this) but seems like setting the seed value manually will be easier and safer.

Obviously, if no new rows are being added to the table (or they're only added occasionally, like a daily ETL process) then this race condition won't happen so `DBCC CHECKIDENT` is fine.

Comment: +1 Do you know the origin of this "trick"? I first came across it in the workarounds to [a connect item](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/252226/allow-enabling-and-disabling-of-a-columns-identity-property) but I see your answer predates this.

Comment: If my memory is correct, I got the idea from this article: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/61979/

Comment: FYI, this appears to also work on the Standard version of SQL 2008 R2. Perhaps they enabled this feature just like they've now enabled the ability to turn on backup compression.

Comment: Mason - great observation!  I updated my answer accordingly. I'd assumed that, because partitions aren't supported in SQL Standard that ALTER TABLE...SWITCH wouldn't be supported either. But given that you can use this command on non-partitioned tables, it makes sense that you can also run it on Standard Edition. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: This is very useful but it doesn't recreate the IDs. It only takes the old ones into the new table. In my case I want to add a ID Identity(1,1) column to an existent table, I don't have the ID values in the old table to fill it...

Comment: @jbatista - the OP's question stated that he already had a primary key on the table and already could ensure the right values, but he simply wanted to change it to be an IDENTITY column. My answer above is focused that narrow use-case: how to add the IDENTITY to a column without actually changing any data. The approach I document above is a huge time-saver for large tables. If you need to change data, then you'll need to use other solutions.

Comment: There's another caveat here that is worth mentioning. Althought the new table will happily receive data from the old table, and all the new rows will be inserted following a identity pattern, *they will start at 1* and potentially break if the said column is a primary key. Consider running `DBCC CHECKIDENT('<newTableName>')` immediately after switching. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057.aspx for more info.

Comment: This is a great answer!  Also note that nullability of columns must be the same. So if you need to change a column nullability, you will have to do it at a later step.  Same goes for PK constraints.  I also change the identity value in the table creation to match the current maximum : IDENTITY (maxID+1, 1)

Comment: If the table is huge enough column `id int NOT NULL` have to be updated with not null incremental values before SWITCH. Which is not 5 seconds, unfortunately. Otherwise this will be error message: ALTER TABLE SWITCH statement failed because column 'id' does not have the same nullability attribute in tables 'Test' and 'Test2'.

Comment: @Alex Peshik - you're correct, this solution (and the OP's question) is about making an existing primary key club into an IDENTITY column. If the column is already a primary key then it's guaranteed to already be NOT NULL.

Comment: So, I liked that trick, but it assumes that the table already has some column populated and we want to turn it into identity. In my case I want to create a new column and have it populated with sequential numbers for a huge table. Is there any trick to make it happen? The table doesn't have any keys.

Comment: @Naomi - Nope. The trick above is only so fast because it doesn't have to change any data in table rows.  What you're asking for will require making changes to every row. That's why it will be slow. And depending on the row size and fill factor, the larger size of each row may split data pages which would make it even slower.

Comment: Just as an addition - I just did this, but I noticed some of the statistics of the indexes now seem to be off. I'm not proficient enough to really understand what is happening, but I thought it might help others to look in the right direction after slow queries.

Comment: The OP question was about changing a primary key column to an identity column. Your response code is about changing an identity column to a non-identity column which could be made primary key afterwards. Could you please add code to reverse that, so your response with match the question

Answer (score 111):

You cannot alter a column to be an IDENTITY column. What you'll need to do is create a new column which is defined as an IDENTITY from the get-go, then drop the old column, and rename the new one to the old name.

```
ALTER TABLE (yourTable) ADD NewColumn INT IDENTITY(1,1)

ALTER TABLE (yourTable) DROP COLUMN OldColumnName

EXEC sp_rename 'yourTable.NewColumn', 'OldColumnName', 'COLUMN'
```

Marc

Comment: Either the parameter \@objname is ambiguous or the claimed \@objtype (COLUMN) is wrong.

Comment: @JennyO'Reilly: put that into a separate question, and **show us** the complete command you're using!

Comment: It was the sp_rename procedure that was failing. I found a solution on stackoverflow by searching for the error text. It seems to be some strict syntax rule with brackets, although my table has no special characters in its name whatsoever.

Comment: or it could be like : 'ALTER TABLE (yourTable) DROP COLUMN OldColumnName' and 'ALTER TABLE (yourTable) ADD OldColumnName INT IDENTITY(1,1)', why rename :p

Comment: Marc, I tried this exact command on a huge table (~300mln rows), but I stopped the process after ~10 min

Answer (score 21):

Consider to use [SEQUENCE instead of IDENTITY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062328/sequence-vs-identity).

In SQL Server 2014 (I don't know about lower versions) you can do this simply, using sequence.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE sequence_name START WITH here_higher_number_than_max_existed_value_in_column INCREMENT BY 1;

ALTER TABLE table_name ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name DEFAULT NEXT VALUE FOR sequence_name FOR column_name
```

From here: [Sequence as default value for a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14413383/sequence-as-default-value-for-a-column)

Comment: Works for my SQL Server 2012, too.

Answer (score 18):

There is cool solution described here:
[SQL SERVER – Add or Remove Identity Property on Column](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/03/sql-server-add-or-remove-identity-property-on-column/)

In short edit manually your table in SQL Manager, switch the identity, DO NOT SAVE changes, just show the script which will be created for the changes, copy it and use it later.

It is huge time saver, because it (the script) contains all the foreign keys, indices, etc. related to the table you change. Writting this manually... God forbid.

Comment: this is the solution i used -- SSMS generates the T-SQL to make the change...it does so by creating a new temp table of the same schema design, then copying all the rows into it, removing the orig, and renaming. can take a little time to run completely but it worked perfectly.

Comment: I don't think Pinal Dave is actually saying you need to run the script that you generate, it is just to show what making the change through the UI does for you...

Comment: This scripting faciity in SSMS (on changing the definition of a table) is actually the only correct facility when documenting a partitioned table. The most appropriate location 'task'->'script table' always forget to script the partitioning function!

Comment: May be helpful to someone. To get the Change Script after changes. Right click the table in design mode on SSMS and select the option "Generate Change Script" and save the script in Local drive

Answer (score 7):

**Simple explanation**

Rename the existing column using sp_RENAME

EXEC sp_RENAME 'Table_Name.Existing_ColumnName' , 'New_ColumnName', 'COLUMN'

**Example for Rename :**

The existing column UserID is renamed as OldUserID

```
EXEC sp_RENAME 'AdminUsers.UserID' , 'OldUserID', 'COLUMN'
```

Then add a new column using alter query to set as primary key and identity value

```
ALTER TABLE TableName ADD Old_ColumnName INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1)
```

**Example for Set Primary key**

The new created column name is UserID

```
ALTER TABLE Users ADD UserID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1)
```

then Drop the Renamed Column

```
ALTER TABLE Table_Name DROP COLUMN Renamed_ColumnName
```

**Example for Drop renamed column**

```
ALTER TABLE Users DROP COLUMN OldUserID
```

Now we've adding a primarykey and identity to the existing column on the table.

Answer (score 5):

I'm a java developer that happened to get on a team without a DBA and one where as a developer, I can't get DBA rights.  I was tasked with moving an entire schema between two databases, so without having a DBA, I had to do it and do it by running scripts, not being able to use the GUI in SQL Server 2008 because I didn't have admin privileges.

Everything was moved without issue, however, when running a stored procedure on the new schema.table, I found I lost the identity field in a table.  I double checked the script that created the table and it was there, however, SQL Server didn't get it when I ran the script.  I was told later by a DBA that he had seen this same problem before.

In any event, for SQL Server 2008, these are the steps I took to get this resolved and they worked, so I'm posting this here in the hopes it will be a help to someone.  This is what I did as I had FK dependencies on another table that made this more difficult:

I used this query to verify the identity was indeed missing and to view dependencies on the table.

1.) Find statistics on a table:

```
exec sp_help 'dbo.table_name_old';
```

2.) Create a duplicate, identical new table, except add an identity field on the PK field where it had been before.

3.) Disable the identity to move data.

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.table_name ON
```

4.) Transfer the data.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.table_name_new
(
field1, field2, etc...
)
SELECT 
field1, field2, etc...
FROM 
dbo.table_name_old;
```

5.) Verify the data is there.

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.table_name_new
```

6.) Re-enable the identity.

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT ToyRecP.ToyAwards.lkpFile_New OFF
```

7.) **This is the best script I found to get all the FK relationships to verify which table(s) the original table references as dependencies
and I came across many, so it is a keeper!**

```
SELECT f.name AS ForeignKey,
   OBJECT_NAME(f.parent_object_id) AS TableName,
   COL_NAME(fc.parent_object_id, fc.parent_column_id) AS ColumnName,
   OBJECT_NAME (f.referenced_object_id) AS ReferenceTableName,
   COL_NAME(fc.referenced_object_id, fc.referenced_column_id) AS ReferenceColumnName
FROM sys.foreign_keys AS f
INNER JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns AS fc
   ON f.OBJECT_ID = fc.constraint_object_id
   ORDER BY ReferenceTableName;
```

8.) Make sure you have all the PK and FK scripts for all the tables involved, before this next step.

9.) You can right-click on each key and script this using SQL Server 2008

10.) Drop the FK(s) from the dependency table(s) using this syntax:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[table_name] DROP CONSTRAINT [Name_of_FK]
```

11.) Drop the original table:

```
DROP TABLE dbo.table_name_old;
```

13.) These next steps rely on the scripts you created in SQL Server 2008 in step 9.

--Add the PK to the new table.

--Add the FK to the new table.

--Add the FK's back to the dependency table.

14.) Verify everything is correct and complete.  I used the GUI to look at the tables.

15.) Rename the new table to the original tables name.

```
exec sp_RENAME '[Schema_Name.OldTableName]' , '[NewTableName]';
```

Finally, everything worked!

Answer (score 5):

As I understood in normal cases we are creating a table with **Primary key** which is having **Identity property**
So **Rename** or **Delete** a column which is associated with **Primary Key** **constraint** will not be possible because constraint Rules are validating column structure.
Tto achieve this we have to process some steps in the following way:
Let us assume **TableName = 'Employee'** and **ColumnName = 'EmployeeId'**


1.  Add new column 'EmployeeId_new' in the 'Employee' table 

**ALTER TABLE Employee ADD EmployeeId_new INT IDENTITY(1,1)**

2. Now remove column 'EmployeeId' from 'Employee' table 

   **ALTER TABLE Employee DROP COLUMN EmployeeId**
3. This will throw error because of Primary Key Constraint rules are applicable and validating column structure.

   *###
   '***Msg 5074, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 The object [PK_dbo.Employee] is dependent on colmn [EmployeeId].'***###
4. So we have to remove the Primary Key constraint first from the table 'Employee' then we can remove the column 

   **ALTER TABLE Employee DROP constraint [PK_dbo.Employee]**
5. Now we can remove the column 'EmployeeId' from 'Employee' table  as did in the previous step where we got error

   **ALTER TABLE Employee DROP COLUMN EmployeeId**
6. Now Column 'EmployeeId' removed from table 
   So we will Rename the newly added new column 'EmployeeId_new' with 'EmployeeId'

   **sp_rename 'Employee.EmployeeId', 'EmployeeId_new', 'COLUMN'**
7. To rearrange the table in the same form as It was, we have to add Primary Key Constraint for the column 'EmployeeId'

   **ALTER TABLE Employee add constraint [PK_dbo.Employee] primary key  (EmployeeId)**

*8. **Now the table 'Employee' with 'EmployeeId' is modified for Identity rules along with existing primary key constraint***

Answer (score 4):

you can't do it like that, you need to add another column, drop the original column and rename the new column or or create a new table, copy the data in and drop the old table followed by renaming the new table to the old table

if you use SSMS and set the identity property to ON in the designer here is what SQL Server does behind the scenes. So if you have a table named [user] this is what happens if you make UserID and identity

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
SET ARITHABORT ON
SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF
SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON
COMMIT
BEGIN TRANSACTION

GO

GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.Tmp_User
    (
    UserID int NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1),
    LastName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    FirstName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    MiddleInitial char(1) NULL

    )  ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Tmp_User ON
GO
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM dbo.[User])
 EXEC('INSERT INTO dbo.Tmp_User (UserID, LastName, FirstName, MiddleInitial)
    SELECT UserID, LastName, FirstName, MiddleInitialFROM dbo.[User] TABLOCKX')
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Tmp_User OFF
GO

GO
DROP TABLE dbo.[User]
GO
EXECUTE sp_rename N'dbo.Tmp_User', N'User', 'OBJECT'
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.[User] ADD CONSTRAINT
    PK_User PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
    UserID
    ) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
COMMIT
```

Having said that there is a way to hack the system table to accomplish it by setting the bitwise value but that is not supported and I wouldn't do it

Answer (score 4):

If you happen to be using Visual Studio 2017+

1. In Server Object Explorer right-click on your table and select "view code"
2. Add the modifier "IDENTITY" to your column
3. Update

This will do it all for you.

Comment: Yes! Thank you for suggesting this! I don' have a version of SSMS on my Windows 7 box that allows me to make Design changes to tables on my Production server because it is 2017, my SSMS is 2014, and 2017 SSMS needs Windows 10. You made my day. Went into VS 2017 > Server Explorer > made a new connection to production SQL Server > right clicked on table > "Open Table Definition" > Wala!

Comment: Actually, I found you can right click on the field and select Properties and make the Identity on there choosing Yes or No.

Answer (score 3):

By design there is no simple way to turn on or turn off the identity feature for an existing column.  The only clean way to do this is to create a new column and make it an identity column or create a new table and migrate your data.

If we use SQL Server Management Studio to get rid of the identity value on column "id", a new temporary table is created, the data is moved to the temporary table, the old table is dropped and the new table is renamed.

Use Management Studio to make the change and then right click in the designer and select "Generate Change Script".

You will see that this is what SQL server in doing in the background.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't one, sadly; the IDENTITY property belongs to the table rather than the column.

The easier way is to do it in the GUI, but if this isn't an option, you can go the long way around of copying the data, dropping the column, re-adding it with identity, and putting the data back.

See [here](http://decipherinfosys.wordpress.com/2007/09/14/altering-a-regular-column-to-be-an-identity-column-in-sql-server/)  for a blow-by-blow account.

Answer (score 2):

If the original poster was actually wanting to set an existing column to be a `PRIMARY KEY` for the table and actually did not need the column to be an `IDENTITY` column (two different things) then this can be done via t-SQL with:

```
ALTER TABLE [YourTableName]
ADD CONSTRAINT [ColumnToSetAsPrimaryKey] PRIMARY KEY ([ColumnToSetAsPrimaryKey])
```

Note the parenthesis around the column name after the `PRIMARY KEY` option.

Although this post is old and I am making an assumption about the requestors need, I felt this additional information could be helpful to users encountering this thread as I believe the conversation could lead one to believe that an existing column can not be set to be a primary key without adding it as a new column first which would be incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

Right click on table name in Object Explorer. You will get some options. Click on 'Design'. A new tab will be opened for this table. You can add Identity constraint here in 'Column Properties'.

Comment: If you do this...the table will be dropped and recreated.

Answer (score 2):

To modify the identity properties for a column:

- In Server Explorer, right-click the table with identity properties you want to modify and click Open Table Definition.
  The table opens in Table Designer.
- Clear the Allow nulls check box for the column you want to change.
- In the Column Properties tab, expand the Identity Specification property.
- Click the grid cell for the Is Identity child property and choose Yes from the drop-down list.
- Type a value in the Identity Seed cell. This value will be assigned to the first row in the table. The value 1 will be assigned by default.

That's it, and it worked for me

Answer (score 2):

In my case there were a lot of tables without identity so copying and recreating were going to take too long. I found an easier way to do it if you are using SQL Server Management Studio:

1. Open ***Tools*** -> ***Options*** -> ***Designers*** -> ***Table and Database Designers***.
2. Uncheck the "***Prevent Saving Changes That Prevent Table Recreation***" checkbox in order not to drop the table and recreate it when changing the table design.
3. Save the changes.
4. Right click on the table and click **Design**.
5. Choose the column, open the properties and select "*Yes*" from the **Identity** dropdown.

The table is not dropped and the data inside the table and the dependencies remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can alter an existing column to be an identity column using tsql.  However, you can do it through the Enterprise Manager design view.

Alternatively you could create a new row as the identity column, drop the old column, then rename your new column.

```
ALTER TABLE FooTable
ADD BarColumn INT IDENTITY(1, 1)
               NOT NULL
               PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
```

Comment: keep in mind that if you do it thru SSMS/Enterprise Manager - you'll be creating a new table, copying data, dropping the old table, and renaming the new one.  That can be quite expensive when you have large tables...

Answer (score 1):

As per my current condition, I follow this approach. I want to give identity to a primary table after data inserted via script.

As I want to append identity, so it always start from 1 to End of record count that I want.

```
--first drop column and add with identity
ALTER TABLE dbo.tblProductPriceList drop column ID 
ALTER TABLE dbo.tblProductPriceList add ID INT IDENTITY(1,1)

--then add primary key to that column (exist option you can ignore)
IF  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.key_constraints  WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[PK_tblProductPriceList]') AND parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[tblProductPriceList]'))
    ALTER TABLE [tblProductPriceList] ADD PRIMARY KEY (id)
GO
```

This will create the same primary key column with identity

I used this links : https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2014/10/11/sql-server-add-auto-incremental-identity-column-to-table-after-creating-table/

[Add primary key to existing table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11794659/add-primary-key-to-existing-table)

Comment: where is all the data that was inside column ID before you dropped it?  are there any foreign keys pointing to colummn ID?

Answer (score 0):

Basically there are four logical steps.

1. Create a new Identity column. Turn on Insert Identity for this new column.
2. Insert the data from the source column (the column you wished to convert to Identity) to this new column.
3. Turn off the Insert Identity for the new column.
4. Drop your source column & rename the new column to the name of the source column.

There may be some more complexities like working across multiple servers etc.

Please refer the following article for the steps (using ssms & T-sql). These steps are intended for beginners with less grip on T-SQL.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/23816.how-to-convert-int-column-to-identity-in-the-ms-sql-server.aspx

Answer (score 0):

generates a script for all tables with primary key = bigint which do not have an identity set; this will return a list of generated scripts with each table;

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

declare @sql table(s varchar(max), id int identity)

DECLARE @table_name nvarchar(max),
        @table_schema nvarchar(max);

DECLARE vendor_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT
  t.name, s.name
FROM sys.schemas AS s
INNER JOIN sys.tables AS t
  ON s.[schema_id] = t.[schema_id]
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT
    [c].[name]
    from sys.columns [c]
    join sys.types [y] on [y].system_type_id = [c].system_type_id
    where [c].[object_id] = [t].[object_id] and [y].name = 'bigint' and [c].[column_id] = 1
) and NOT EXISTS 
(
  SELECT 1 FROM sys.identity_columns
    WHERE [object_id] = t.[object_id]
) and exists (
    select 1 from sys.indexes as [i] 
    inner join sys.index_columns as [ic]  ON  i.OBJECT_ID = ic.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = ic.index_id
    where object_name([ic].[object_id]) = [t].[name]
)
OPEN vendor_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM vendor_cursor 
INTO @table_name, @table_schema

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

DELETE FROM @sql

declare @pkname varchar(100),
    @pkcol nvarchar(100)

SELECT  top 1
        @pkname = i.name,
        @pkcol = COL_NAME(ic.OBJECT_ID,ic.column_id)
FROM    sys.indexes AS [i]
INNER JOIN sys.index_columns AS [ic] ON  i.OBJECT_ID = ic.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = ic.index_id
WHERE   i.is_primary_key = 1 and OBJECT_NAME(ic.OBJECT_ID) = @table_name

declare @q nvarchar(max) = 'SELECT  '+@pkcol+' FROM ['+@table_schema+'].['+@table_name+'] ORDER BY '+@pkcol+' DESC'

DECLARE @ident_seed nvarchar(max) -- Change this to the datatype that you are after
SET @q = REPLACE(@q, 'SELECT', 'SELECT TOP 1 @output = ')
EXEC sp_executeSql @q, N'@output bigint OUTPUT', @ident_seed OUTPUT

insert into  @sql(s) values ('BEGIN TRANSACTION')
insert into  @sql(s) values ('BEGIN TRY')

-- create statement
insert into  @sql(s) values ('create table ['+@table_schema+'].[' + @table_name + '_Temp] (')

-- column list
insert into @sql(s) 
select 
    '  ['+[c].[name]+'] ' +
    y.name + 

    (case when [y].[name] like '%varchar' then
    coalesce('('+(case when ([c].[max_length] < 0 or [c].[max_length] >= 1024) then 'max' else cast([c].max_length as varchar) end)+')','')
    else '' end)

     + ' ' +
    case when [c].name = @pkcol then 'IDENTITY(' +COALESCE(@ident_seed, '1')+',1)' else '' end + ' ' +
    ( case when c.is_nullable = 0 then 'NOT ' else '' end ) + 'NULL ' + 
    coalesce('DEFAULT ('+(
        REPLACE(
            REPLACE(
                LTrim(
                    RTrim(
                        REPLACE(
                            REPLACE(
                                REPLACE(
                                    REPLACE(
                                        LTrim(
                                            RTrim(
                                                REPLACE(
                                                    REPLACE(
                                                        object_definition([c].default_object_id)
                                                    ,' ','~')
                                                ,')',' ')
                                            )
                                        )
                                    ,' ','*')
                                ,'~',' ')
                            ,' ','~')
                        ,'(',' ')
                    )
                )
            ,' ','*')
        ,'~',' ')
    ) +
    case when object_definition([c].default_object_id) like '%get%date%' then '()' else '' end
    +
    ')','') + ','
 from sys.columns c
 JOIN sys.types y ON y.system_type_id = c.system_type_id
  where OBJECT_NAME(c.[object_id]) = @table_name and [y].name != 'sysname'
 order by [c].column_id


 update @sql set s=left(s,len(s)-1) where id=@@identity

-- closing bracket
insert into @sql(s) values( ')' )

insert into @sql(s) values( 'SET IDENTITY_INSERT ['+@table_schema+'].['+@table_name+'_Temp] ON')

declare @cols nvarchar(max)
SELECT @cols = STUFF(
    (
        select ',['+c.name+']'
        from sys.columns c
        JOIN sys.types y ON y.system_type_id = c.system_type_id
        where c.[object_id] = OBJECT_ID(@table_name)
        and [y].name != 'sysname'
        and [y].name != 'timestamp'
        order by [c].column_id
        FOR XML PATH ('')
     )
    , 1, 1, '')

insert into @sql(s) values( 'IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM ['+@table_schema+'].['+@table_name+'])')
insert into @sql(s) values( 'EXEC(''INSERT INTO ['+@table_schema+'].['+@table_name+'_Temp] ('+@cols+')')
insert into @sql(s) values( 'SELECT '+@cols+' FROM ['+@table_schema+'].['+@table_name+']'')')

insert into @sql(s) values( 'SET IDENTITY_INSERT ['+@table_schema+'].['+@table_name+'_Temp] OFF')


insert into @sql(s) values( 'DROP TABLE ['+@table_schema+'].['+@table_name+']')

insert into @sql(s) values( 'EXECUTE sp_rename N''['+@table_schema+'].['+@table_name+'_Temp]'', N'''+@table_name+''', ''OBJECT''')

if ( @pkname is not null ) begin
    insert into @sql(s) values('ALTER TABLE ['+@table_schema+'].['+@table_name+'] ADD CONSTRAINT ['+@pkname+'] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (')
    insert into @sql(s)
        select '  ['+COLUMN_NAME+'] ASC,' from information_schema.key_column_usage
        where constraint_name = @pkname
        GROUP BY COLUMN_NAME, ordinal_position
        order by ordinal_position

    -- remove trailing comma
    update @sql set s=left(s,len(s)-1) where id=@@identity
    insert into @sql(s) values ('  )')
end

insert into  @sql(s) values ('--Run your Statements')
insert into  @sql(s) values ('COMMIT TRANSACTION')
insert into  @sql(s) values ('END TRY')
insert into  @sql(s) values ('BEGIN CATCH')
insert into  @sql(s) values ('        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION')
insert into  @sql(s) values ('        DECLARE @Msg NVARCHAR(MAX)  ')
insert into  @sql(s) values ('        SELECT @Msg=ERROR_MESSAGE() ')
insert into  @sql(s) values ('        RAISERROR(''Error Occured: %s'', 20, 101,@msg) WITH LOG')
insert into  @sql(s) values ('END CATCH')

declare @fqry nvarchar(max)

-- result!
SELECT @fqry = (select char(10) + s from @sql order by id FOR XML PATH (''))


SELECT @table_name as [Table_Name], @fqry as [Generated_Query]
PRINT 'Table: '+@table_name
EXEC sp_executeSql @fqry

    FETCH NEXT FROM vendor_cursor 
    INTO @table_name, @table_schema
END 
CLOSE vendor_cursor;
DEALLOCATE vendor_cursor;
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is very similar to [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77545901/10027033), with little differences.

For example you have 3 tables like this, with two foreign key

**DDL:**

```
CREATE TABLE [Table_1]
(
    [id] [int] NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [Name] [varchar](10) NULL
)
GO

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX Table_1_Index   
ON [Table_1] ([Name]);

CREATE TABLE [Table_2]
(
    [id] [int] NOT NULL  
         FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [Table_1]([id]) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    [car] [varchar](10) NULL
)
GO

CREATE TABLE [Table_3]
(
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [Name] [varchar](10) NULL 
         FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [Table_1]([Name])
)
GO

INSERT INTO [Table_1] 
VALUES (10000, 'John'), (10001, 'Mike')

INSERT INTO [Table_2] 
VALUES (10000, 'Benz'), (10000, 'Volvo'), (10001, 'BMW')

INSERT INTO [Table_3] 
VALUES ('John')
GO
```

If you want add identity to `id` column in `Table_1` with `dbo` schema, and want to start from 10000 with 1 increment, run this query:

```
DECLARE @Schema SysName = 'dbo'
DECLARE @TableName SysName = 'Table_1'
DECLARE @ColumnName SysName = 'id'
DECLARE @IdentityType VARCHAR(20) = 'IDENTITY(10000,1)'

DECLARE @Table_Name SYSNAME = QUOTENAME(@Schema) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@TableName)
DECLARE @SQLCreateTable NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @SQLFK NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

--get foreign keys
;WITH fk_columns AS 
(
    SELECT
        constraint_object_id, 
        OBJECT_NAME(constraint_object_id) KeyName,  
        OBJECT_NAME(fkc.parent_object_id) FKTable,  
        OBJECT_NAME(fkc.referenced_object_id) PKTable,
        COL_NAME(fkc.parent_object_id, parent_column_id) FKColumn, 
        COL_NAME(fkc.referenced_object_id, referenced_column_id) PKColumn,
        delete_referential_action,
        update_referential_action, 
        is_not_trusted
    FROM
        sys.foreign_key_columns fkc
    JOIN 
        sys.foreign_keys fk ON fk.object_id = fkc.constraint_object_id
    WHERE 
        fkc.referenced_object_id = OBJECT_ID(@Table_Name)
)
SELECT 
    @SQLFK = ISNULL((SELECT (
        SELECT CHAR(13) +
             'ALTER TABLE ' + fk.FKTable + ' WITH' 
            + CASE WHEN fk.is_not_trusted = 1 
                THEN ' NOCHECK' 
                ELSE ' CHECK' 
              END + 
              ' ADD CONSTRAINT [' + fk.KeyName  + '] FOREIGN KEY(' 
              + STUFF((
                SELECT
                    ', [' + k.FKColumn + ']'
                FROM
                    fk_columns k
                WHERE
                    k.constraint_object_id = fk.constraint_object_id
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '')
               + ')' +
              ' REFERENCES '+@Table_Name+' ('
              + STUFF((
                SELECT
                    ', [' + k.PKColumn + ']'
                FROM
                    fk_columns k
                WHERE
                    k.constraint_object_id = fk.constraint_object_id
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '')
               + ')'
            + CASE 
                WHEN fk.delete_referential_action = 1 THEN ' ON DELETE CASCADE' 
                WHEN fk.delete_referential_action = 2 THEN ' ON DELETE SET NULL'
                WHEN fk.delete_referential_action = 3 THEN ' ON DELETE SET DEFAULT' 
                ELSE '' 
              END
            + CASE 
                WHEN fk.update_referential_action = 1 THEN ' ON UPDATE CASCADE'
                WHEN fk.update_referential_action = 2 THEN ' ON UPDATE SET NULL'
                WHEN fk.update_referential_action = 3 THEN ' ON UPDATE SET DEFAULT'  
                ELSE '' 
              END 
            + CHAR(13) + 'ALTER TABLE ' + fk.FKTable + ' CHECK CONSTRAINT [' + fk.KeyName  + ']' + CHAR(13)
        FROM fk_columns fk WITH (NOWAIT)
        FOR XML PATH(N''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')), '')

--drop foreign keys
;WITH fk_columns AS 
(
    SELECT
        OBJECT_NAME(constraint_object_id) KeyName,
        OBJECT_NAME(fkc.parent_object_id) FKTable
    FROM
        sys.foreign_key_columns fkc
    JOIN
        sys.foreign_keys fk ON fk.object_id = fkc.constraint_object_id
    WHERE
        fkc.referenced_object_id = OBJECT_ID(@Table_Name)
)
SELECT @SQL = ISNULL((SELECT (
        SELECT
             CHAR(13) + 'ALTER TABLE ' + fk.FKTable +
             ' DROP CONSTRAINT [' + fk.KeyName + ']' + CHAR(13)
        FROM
            fk_columns fk WITH (NOWAIT)
        FOR XML PATH(N''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')), '')
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL

--find not exist table name
DECLARE @i INT = 1
WHILE OBJECT_ID(QUOTENAME(@Schema) + '.' +QUOTENAME(@TableName) + '_Temp' + CAST(@i AS varchar), 'U') IS NOT NULL
    SET @i += 1
DECLARE @TempName SysName = @TableName + '_Temp' + CAST(@i AS VARCHAR)
DECLARE @Temp_Name SysName = QUOTENAME(@Schema) + '.' +QUOTENAME(@TableName + '_Temp' + CAST(@i AS VARCHAR))

--create temp table like table code
DECLARE @object_id INT = OBJECT_ID(@Table_Name)
;WITH index_column AS 
(
    SELECT 
        ic.[object_id],
        ic.index_id,
        ic.is_descending_key,
        ic.is_included_column,
        c.name
    FROM
        sys.index_columns ic WITH (NOWAIT)
    JOIN
        sys.columns c WITH (NOWAIT) ON ic.[object_id] = c.[object_id] AND ic.column_id = c.column_id
    WHERE
        ic.[object_id] = @object_id
),
fk_columns AS 
(
     SELECT 
        k.constraint_object_id,
        cname = c.name,
        rcname = rc.name
    FROM
        sys.foreign_key_columns k WITH (NOWAIT)
    JOIN
        sys.columns rc WITH (NOWAIT) ON rc.[object_id] = k.referenced_object_id AND rc.column_id = k.referenced_column_id 
    JOIN
        sys.columns c WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.[object_id] = k.parent_object_id AND c.column_id = k.parent_column_id
    WHERE
        k.parent_object_id = @object_id
)
SELECT @SQLCreateTable = 'CREATE TABLE ' + @Temp_Name + CHAR(13) + '(' + CHAR(13) + STUFF((
    SELECT
        CHAR(9) + ', [' + c.name + '] ' + 
        CASE WHEN c.is_computed = 1
            THEN 'AS ' + cc.[definition] 
            ELSE UPPER(tp.name) + 
                CASE WHEN tp.name IN ('varchar', 'char', 'varbinary', 'binary', 'text')
                       THEN '(' + CASE WHEN c.max_length = -1 THEN 'MAX' ELSE CAST(c.max_length AS VARCHAR(5)) END + ')'
                     WHEN tp.name IN ('nvarchar', 'nchar', 'ntext')
                       THEN '(' + CASE WHEN c.max_length = -1 THEN 'MAX' ELSE CAST(c.max_length / 2 AS VARCHAR(5)) END + ')'
                     WHEN tp.name IN ('datetime2', 'time2', 'datetimeoffset') 
                       THEN '(' + CAST(c.scale AS VARCHAR(5)) + ')'
                    WHEN tp.name IN ('decimal', 'numeric')
                       THEN '(' + CAST(c.[precision] AS VARCHAR(5)) + ',' + CAST(c.scale AS VARCHAR(5)) + ')'
                    ELSE ''
                END +
                CASE WHEN c.collation_name IS NOT NULL THEN ' COLLATE ' + c.collation_name ELSE '' END +
                CASE WHEN c.name = @ColumnName THEN ' ' +@IdentityType ELSE '' END +
                CASE WHEN c.is_nullable = 1 and c.name <> @ColumnName THEN ' NULL' ELSE ' NOT NULL' END +
                CASE WHEN dc.[definition] IS NOT NULL and c.name <> @ColumnName THEN ' DEFAULT' + dc.[definition] ELSE '' END
            END + CHAR(13)
    FROM
        sys.columns c WITH (NOWAIT)
    JOIN 
        sys.types tp WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.user_type_id = tp.user_type_id
    LEFT JOIN
        sys.computed_columns cc WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.[object_id] = cc.[object_id] AND c.column_id = cc.column_id
    LEFT JOIN
        sys.default_constraints dc WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.default_object_id != 0 AND c.[object_id] = dc.parent_object_id AND c.column_id = dc.parent_column_id
    LEFT JOIN
        sys.identity_columns ic WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.is_identity = 1 AND c.[object_id] = ic.[object_id] AND c.column_id = ic.column_id
    WHERE
        c.[object_id] = @object_id
    ORDER BY
        c.column_id
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, CHAR(9) + ' ')
    + ISNULL((SELECT CHAR(9) + ', CONSTRAINT [' + k.name + '] PRIMARY KEY (' + 
                    (SELECT STUFF((
                         SELECT ', [' + c.name + '] ' + CASE WHEN ic.is_descending_key = 1 THEN 'DESC' ELSE 'ASC' END
                         FROM
                            sys.index_columns ic WITH (NOWAIT)
                         JOIN
                            sys.columns c WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.[object_id] = ic.[object_id] AND c.column_id = ic.column_id
                         WHERE
                            ic.is_included_column = 0
                            AND ic.[object_id] = k.parent_object_id 
                            AND ic.index_id = k.unique_index_id     
                         FOR XML PATH(N''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, ''))
            + ')' + CHAR(13)
            FROM
                sys.key_constraints k WITH (NOWAIT)
            WHERE
                k.parent_object_id = @object_id 
                AND k.[type] = 'PK'), '') + ')'  + CHAR(13)
    + ISNULL((SELECT (
        SELECT CHAR(13) +
             'ALTER TABLE ' + @Temp_Name + ' WITH' 
            + CASE WHEN fk.is_not_trusted = 1 
                THEN ' NOCHECK' 
                ELSE ' CHECK' 
              END + 
              ' ADD CONSTRAINT [' + fk.name  + '] FOREIGN KEY(' 
              + STUFF((
                SELECT
                    ', [' + k.cname + ']'
                FROM
                    fk_columns k
                WHERE
                    k.constraint_object_id = fk.[object_id]
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '')
               + ')' +
              ' REFERENCES [' + SCHEMA_NAME(ro.[schema_id]) + '].[' + ro.name + '] ('
              + STUFF((
                SELECT
                    ', [' + k.rcname + ']'
                FROM
                    fk_columns k
                WHERE
                    k.constraint_object_id = fk.[object_id]
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '')
               + ')'
            + CASE 
                WHEN fk.delete_referential_action = 1 THEN ' ON DELETE CASCADE' 
                WHEN fk.delete_referential_action = 2 THEN ' ON DELETE SET NULL'
                WHEN fk.delete_referential_action = 3 THEN ' ON DELETE SET DEFAULT' 
                ELSE '' 
              END
            + CASE 
                WHEN fk.update_referential_action = 1 THEN ' ON UPDATE CASCADE'
                WHEN fk.update_referential_action = 2 THEN ' ON UPDATE SET NULL'
                WHEN fk.update_referential_action = 3 THEN ' ON UPDATE SET DEFAULT'  
                ELSE '' 
              END 
            + CHAR(13) + 'ALTER TABLE ' + @Temp_Name + ' CHECK CONSTRAINT [' + fk.name  + ']' + CHAR(13)
        FROM sys.foreign_keys fk WITH (NOWAIT)
        JOIN sys.objects ro WITH (NOWAIT) ON ro.[object_id] = fk.referenced_object_id
        WHERE fk.parent_object_id = @object_id
        FOR XML PATH(N''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')), '')
    + ISNULL(((SELECT
         CHAR(13) + 'CREATE' + CASE WHEN i.is_unique = 1 THEN ' UNIQUE' ELSE '' END
                + CASE i.type WHEN 1 THEN ' CLUSTERED' ELSE ' NONCLUSTERED' END
                + ' INDEX [' + i.name + '] ON ' + @Temp_Name + ' (' +
                STUFF((
                SELECT ', [' + c.name + ']' + CASE WHEN c.is_descending_key = 1 THEN ' DESC' ELSE ' ASC' END
                FROM
                    index_column c
                WHERE
                    c.is_included_column = 0
                    AND c.index_id = i.index_id
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '') + ')'  
                + ISNULL(CHAR(13) + 'INCLUDE (' + 
                    STUFF((
                    SELECT
                        ', [' + c.name + ']'
                    FROM
                        index_column c
                    WHERE
                        c.is_included_column = 1
                        AND c.index_id = i.index_id
                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '') + ')', '')  + CHAR(13)
        FROM
            sys.indexes i WITH (NOWAIT)
        WHERE
            i.[object_id] = @object_id
            AND i.is_primary_key = 0
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
    ), '')

--rename primary key constaint on column from table
DECLARE @PrimaryName SYSNAME
SELECT @PrimaryName=i.name
    FROM
        sys.index_columns ic WITH (NOWAIT)
    JOIN
        sys.indexes i WITH (NOWAIT) ON i.object_id = ic.object_id and i.index_id = ic.index_id
    WHERE
        i.object_id = OBJECT_ID(@Table_Name) and Col_Name(ic.object_id, column_id) = @ColumnName and is_primary_key = 1
SET @SQL = N'EXEC sp_rename ' + @PrimaryName + ', ' + 'ThisMustNotBeExist'+ @PrimaryName + ', N''OBJECT'''
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL
--rename index on column from table
DECLARE @IndexName SYSNAME
SELECT
    @IndexName = i.name
FROM
    sys.index_columns ic WITH (NOWAIT)
JOIN
    sys.indexes i WITH (NOWAIT) ON i.object_id = ic.object_id AND i.index_id = ic.index_id
WHERE
    i.object_id = OBJECT_ID(@Table_Name)
    AND Col_Name(ic.object_id, column_id) = @ColumnName
    AND is_primary_key = 0
SET @SQL = N'EXEC sp_rename ' + @Table_Name + '.' + @IndexName + ', ' + 'ThisMustNotBeExist'+ @IndexName + ', N''INDEX''' 
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL

--run create temp table like table code
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLCreateTable

--Move table data to temp data
SET @SQL = N'ALTER TABLE '+ @Table_Name + ' SWITCH TO ' + @Temp_Name
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL

--check clean up 
SET @SQL = N'IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM '+ @Table_Name + ') THROW 50000, ''Table is not clear'', 1'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL

--drop table
SET @SQL = N'DROP TABLE '+ @Table_Name
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL

--rename temp table to table
EXEC sys.sp_rename @Temp_Name, @TableName, 'OBJECT';

--create foreign keys
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLFK

DBCC CHECKIDENT(@TableName, RESEED)
```

**Note**

- This code only copy keys and indexes, if you have other things on that table, you loose them after running this code

If you want copy triggers or extended property of the table too, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77526529/10027033) and add `@SQL2` and `@SQL3` to `@SQLCreateTable` before executing it