# Concatenate value to generated unique ID

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an existing table named `Employee` and have to add a new column `Employee_Id`. 
`EmployeeId` should be 10 digit unique number and always have to start with `10`.

For example

```
1000000000
1000000001
1023456789
```

So I need to add bunch of unique 10 digit Id's to an existing table which already has data.

Can anyone help me sort this out.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT 1000000000 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY YourColumn ) AS 'rownumber',*
    FROM Employee
```

This will get the data from the existing table, with an extra column for the new id.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using SQL Server, IDENTITY would help you.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx

**Update:** You should see the discussion here in order to alter table.

[Adding an identity to an existing column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049210/adding-an-identity-to-an-existing-column)

Comment: it's not going to help with the existing data unless whole of it is reinserted right?

Comment: Then, similar discussion is here. How about this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049210/adding-an-identity-to-an-existing-column

Comment: but that is in case if you already have one, the OP didn't mention that, @user1078389 do you already have a primary key?

Answer (score 2):

If you already have and integer PK, you may add a calculated column (persisted or not). It value will be PK + 1000000000, provided no pk is bigger than 1000000000.

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE YOURTABLE
ADD COLUMNNAME INTEGER IDENTITY(1000000000, 1)
```

It will not generate all with 10.. but it will generate al the possibilities, if it get passed you will get 11.. but that would be a lot of numbers to reach that.

Hope it helps

Comment: `integer` -> `int` in SQL Server.