# Using correlated subquery in SQL Server update statement gives unexpected result

Tags: sql, sql-server, correlated-subquery

I'm introducing a primary key column to a table that doesn't have one yet. After I have added a normal field `Id` (int) with a default value of 0 I tried using the following update statement to create unique values for each record:

```
update t1
set t1.id = (select count(*) from mytable t2 where t2.id <> t1.id)
from mytable t1
```

I would expect the subquery to be executed for each row because I'm referencing `t1`. Each time the subquery would be executed the count should be one less but it doesn't work.

The result is that Id is still 0 in every record. I have used this before on other DBMS with success. I'm using SQL Server 2008 here.

How do I generate unique values for each record and update the Id field?

Comment: Why aren't you just adding a `ID INT IDENTITY(1,1)` column?? Then SQL Server will automatically take care of creating unique values for `ID` and you don't have to update anything at all.....

Comment: Thanks. I'll try. I work with many different DBMS so I always try the most generic approach.

Answer (score 4):

Trying to explain why **it doesn't work as you expect**:

> I would expect the subquery to be executed for each row because I'm referencing t1.

It is executed and it can affect all rows. But an `UPDATE` stetement is one statement and it is executed as one statement that affects a whole table (or a part of it if you have a `WHERE` clause).

> Each time the subquery would be executed the count should be one less but it doesn't work.

You are expecting the `UPDATE` to be executed with one evaluation of the subquery per row. But it is one statement that is first evaluated - for all affected rows - and then the rows are changed (updated). (A DBMS may do it otherwise but the result should be nonetheless **as if** it was doing it this way).

> The result is that Id is still 0 in every record.

That's the correct and expected behaviour of this statement when all rows have the same `0` value before execution. The `COUNT(*)` is `0`.

> I have used this before on other DBMS with success.

My "wild" guess is that you have used it in MySQL. (Correction/Update: my guess was wrong, this syntax for Update is not valid for MySQL, apparently the query was working "correctly" in Firebird). The `UPDATE` does not work in the standard way in that DBMS. It works - as you have learned - row by row, not with the full table.

> I'm using SQL Server 2008 here.

This DBMS works correctly with `UPDATE`. You can write a different Update statement that would have the wanted results or, even better, use an autogenerated `IDENTITY` column, as others have advised.

Comment: Thanks for you elaborate reply. I was expecting the row by row behavior like you said (also in Firebird DBMS).

Comment: Your account sounds horribly plausible :) But I have to ask: does the same update in mySQL really work as the OP expected? It's just that it is so not how SQL is supposed to work!

Comment: You're absolutely right. I don't know about MySQL behavior in this situation.

Comment: The query does not work as it is in MySQL (I was wrong about that). The syntax is different (`UPDATE ... FROM ... SET ...`) and you can't specify the same table both as the target of Update and inside the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @onedaywhen: This query does not work in MySQL. But MySQL's `UPDATE` works in non-standard way. You can't do for example `UPDATE t SET id = id+1` if `id` is Unique or Primary Key (you'll get duplicate Primary Key error). You can however do: `UPDATE t SET id = id+1 ORDER BY id DESC` (no duplicates this way which clearly shows that rows are updated and constraints checked row by row!)

Comment: Columns are also updated from left to right (when in the same table), which is also non-standard behaviour. Reference here: `This behavior differs from standard SQL.` [MySQL UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/update.html)

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I've not really used mySQL so I shouldn't judge but revelation such as these really put me off it!

Answer (score 1):

The SQL is updating every row with the number of records where the ID doesn't equal 0. As all the rows ID equal 0 then there are no rows that are not equal to 0, and hence nothing gets updated.

Try looking at this answer here:

[Adding an identity to an existing column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049210/adding-an-identity-to-an-existing-column)

Comment: Instead I used this script to update the Id field: `DECLARE count INT
    SET count = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MYTABLE WHERE ID = 0)
    WHILE (count > 0)
    BEGIN
      UPDATE TOP (1) MYTABLE SET ID=@count WHERE ID=0
      SET count = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MYTABLE WHERE ID = 0)
    END`