# Bulk increment sequence within MS SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Postgres and Oracle include generate_series/connect by command to allow incrementing a sequence by more than 1. I have a need to increment a sequence by a variable amount before row insertion. For example in Postgres this would look like the query below:

`select nextval('mytable_seq') from generate_series(1,3);`

What would be the recommended way to accomplish this in Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  Just using `identity` and give an argument for the increment amount.

Comment: @GordonLinoff see http://stackoverflow.com/a/10062436/1186165. The fact that an identity is "tied" to a table is a major limitation in some settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [stored procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-sequence-get-range-transact-sql) call you can use. Alternatively, you could set up some sort of `while` loop that calls `next value for` multiple times and caches them for use later.

Answer (score 0):

Old question - new answer:

Assuming you've defined your sequence as:

```
create sequence dbo.IdSequence 
as bigint 
start with 1
```

...you can just include the phrase `next value for dbo.IdSequence` as a column in a select statement. When I have a sequence values I want to be paired to a result set, I'll do something like:

```
select
   next value for dbo.IdSequence as Seq,
   someSource.Col1,
   someSource.Col2  --> ... and so on
from
   dbo.someSource
```

If I have a need for a specific number of sequence values, I'll use some kind of sql table-valued function that generates dummy values:

```
select 
    next value for dbo.IdSequence Seq
from
    dbo.FromTo( 1, 5 )
```

Note that if you make two columns requesting values from the same sequence, they'll return the same value for each column. It's probably not what you want:

```
select 
    next value for dbo.IdSequence Seq1,
    next value for dbo.IdSequence Seq2
from
    dbo.FromTo( 1, 5 )
```

...returns something like:

```
Seq1    Seq2
--------------------------
549     549
550     550
551     551
552     552
553     553
```

The `FromTo` is a simple function that generates numbers. There are lots of great examples of functions that do this in (lots of) answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21425546/how-to-generate-a-range-of-numbers-between-two-numbers).