# sql server key field

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with in my sql server database that is a key field which consists of a number (ex. 1-50,000). Is there a way to insert that key number into the database when entering data and start from the last known value?

Comment: I believe you're looking for the IDENTITY field: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx

Comment: can't you use an autonumeric identity field? Does not suit in your solution?

Comment: Please check [Adding an identity to an existing column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049210/adding-an-identity-to-an-existing-column).

Answer (score 0):

Set the Identity Seed value of your field to the number you want to start from

ex.
if you want to start from 10000
so your next value will be 10001,

[image: identity seed]