# How Can I ALTER COLUMN to NOT NULL and ADD PRIMARY KEY in the same SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a column `my_id` which is already set as `varchar(50)` `NULL`. Now I want to alter it to `NOT NULL` and add it as `primary key` for that table. Since there is no other primary keys yet.
I have written like below.

```
ALTER TABLE my_details
ALTER COLUMN my_id varchar(50) NOT NULL;

ALTER TABLE my_details
ADD PRIMARY KEY (my_id);
```

But I get an error:

> Cannot define PRIMARY KEY constraint on nullable column in table 'my_details'. Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

How to write a single query for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add primary key to existing table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11794659/add-primary-key-to-existing-table)

Comment: You cannot do this in a single query - you need the two steps - first convert column to be `NOT NULL`, and in a second step, add the primary key constraint to the table with that newly non-nullable column

Answer (score 7):

Just place a `GO` between two commands, to execute them separately:

```
ALTER TABLE my_details
ALTER COLUMN my_id varchar(50) NOT NULL;

GO

ALTER TABLE my_details
ADD PRIMARY KEY (my_id);
```

Answer (score 4):

Using GO is not always an option, such as inside a stored procedure.

The workaround for me was to use dynamic SQL to bypass the excessive, premature schema validation:

```
create table #test(ID int not null, ForeignKeyID int null)
alter table #test alter column ForeignKeyID int not null
exec ('alter table #test add primary key(ID, ForeignKeyID)')
```

Of course, as Cool_Br33ze mentioned, you need to ensure there are no NULLs in the column(s) you are updating beforehand.

P.S. I am unable to directly reproduce the error, but have seen it occurring (on PROD unfortunately).

Answer (score 0):

if this is an existing table with nulls in the my_id column then you have to update the column to remove the nulls first

```
CREATE TABLE my_details ( my_id varchar(50) NULL )
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.my_details ( my_id ) VALUES (NULL  )
GO

ALTER TABLE my_details
ALTER COLUMN my_id varchar(50) NOT NULL;
GO
```

Gives you this error

> Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 9 Cannot insert the value NULL into
>   column 'my_id', table 'xStuff.dbo.my_details'; column does not allow
>   nulls. UPDATE fails.

trying to add a primary key gives you this

```
ALTER TABLE my_details
ADD PRIMARY KEY (my_id); 
GO
```

> Msg 8111, Level 16, State 1, Line 16 Cannot define PRIMARY KEY
>   constraint on nullable column in table 'my_details'. Msg 1750, Level
>   16, State 0, Line 16 Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

However

place an update in between and this change works

```
CREATE TABLE my_details ( my_id varchar(50) NULL );
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.my_details ( my_id ) VALUES (NULL  );
GO

UPDATE dbo.my_details SET my_id = '' WHERE my_id IS NULL;
GO

ALTER TABLE my_details
ALTER COLUMN my_id varchar(50) NOT NULL;
GO

ALTER TABLE my_details
ADD PRIMARY KEY (my_id); 
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

1 step : make your column not null
query->   alter table employees alter column emp_id integer NOT NULL;

2 step : now after updating column add primary key into that column
query - > alter table employees ADD PRIMARY KEY (emp_id);