# Writing DataGridView Changes back to a SQL database

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, vb.net

I am a bit new to C# and using DataGridViews, but I was able to connect my database to VS 2022 and display the data in a grid using the default code. I have edited my TableAdapter using the `.xsd` and configuring it through the TableAdapter Configuration Wizard. I was able to set my Select and Insert commands here, but the Update and Delete commands seem to be escaping me. When I use the built in functions to save the data back to the DB, it will only work if a new line is added.

To put it simply, I am unable to add/change any information in existing rows, but I can add new rows to the table and update just fine.

When I try to change any existing row's data, I get an error:

> Update requires a valid UpdateCommand when passed DataRow collection with modified rows

Now I am assuming this is because the UPDATE SQL query has not been set in the TableAdapter, and when I add a new line, it works fine because it relies on the Insert command, not the Update command.

My idea is to track when a row is changed so that I can create a custom UPDATE query each time, build a SQL command out of it, and then update only that row each time. I have gotten this far, but it doesn't seem to actually update the row at all.

```
namespace AssetListAccessTool_v1._2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void computersBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Validate();
            this.computersBindingSource.EndEdit();
            //this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.computers);
            UpdateRowToDB();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'computers._Computers' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.computersTableAdapter.Fill(this.computers._Computers);

        }

        //Tracks for PositionChanged event last row
        private DataRow LastDataRow = null;

        //Checks if there is a row with changes and writes to Data Base
        private void UpdateRowToDB()
        {
            if (LastDataRow != null && LastDataRow.RowState == DataRowState.Modified)
            {
                this.computersTableAdapter.Update(LastDataRow);
            }
        }

        private void regionBindingSource_PositionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //if the user moves to a new row, check if the last row was changed
            BindingSource thisBidingSource = (BindingSource)sender;
            DataRow ThisDataRow = ((DataRowView)thisBidingSource.Current).Row;

            if (ThisDataRow == LastDataRow)
            {
                //we need to avoid to write a datarow to the database when it is still processes.
                //Otherwise we get a problem with the event handling of the data table

                throw new ApplicationException("It seems the" + " PositionChanged event was fired twice for" + " the same row");
            }

            UpdateRowToDB();
            //track the current row for next PositionChanged Event
            LastDataRow = ThisDataRow;
        }

        private void ComputersForm_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            UpdateRowToDB();
        }
    }
}
```

Please let me know where you see missing gaps or if you need extra info. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: >I am unable to add/change any information in existing rows

If you do not have an auto-incrementing primary key this can be the issue as a auto-incrementing primary key is needed for updates and deletes.

Comment: @KarenPayne I am not sure how to set the primary key. Is that the connection string?

Comment: if this is SQL-Server the best way is to use SQL-Server Management Studio (its free) or see the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11794659/add-primary-key-to-existing-table)

Comment: Look at the table definition in your database. Does it have a primary key set?  If not, how do you uniquely identify the row you want to update?  You should be able to build the update command manually in the designer. Select the dataAdapter, choose properties and expand the UpdateCommand property to set the CommandText