# How to add a row number to new table in SQL?

Tags: sql-server-2005, insert-into

I'm trying to create a new table using an existing table already using:

```
INSERT INTO NewTable (...,...)
   SELECT * from SampleTable
```

What I need to is add a record number at the beginning or the end, it really doesn't matter as long as it's there.

**Sample Table**

```
Elizabeth  RI 02914
Emily      MA 01834
```

**Prospective New Table**

```
1 Elizabeth  RI 02914
2 Emily      MA 01834
```

Is that at all possible?

This is what I ultimately I'm shooting for... except right now those tables aren't the same size because I need my ErrorTemporaryTable to have a column in which the first row has a number which increments by the previous one by one.

```
declare @counter int
declare @ClientMessage varchar(255)
declare @TestingMessage carchar(255)
select @counter = (select count(*) + 1 as counter from ErrorValidationTesting)
while @counter <= (select count(*) from ErrorValidationTable ET, ErrorValidationMessage EM where ET.Error = EM.Error_ID)
begin
    insert into ErrorValidationTesting (Validation_Error_ID, Program_ID, Displayed_ID, Client_Message, Testing_Message, Create_Date)
    select * from ErrorTemporaryTable

    select @counter = @counter + 1

end
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use `into` clause with `IDENTITY` column:

```
SELECT IDENTITY(int, 1,1) AS ID_Num, col0, col1
INTO NewTable
FROM OldTable;
```

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189838.aspx) is more information

You can also create table with `identity` field:

```
create table NewTable
(
  id int IDENTITY,
  col0 varchar(30),
  col1 varchar(30)
)
```

and insert:

```
insert into NewTable (col0, col1)
SELECT col0, col1   
FROM OldTable;
```

or if you have NewTable and you want to add new column see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049210/adding-an-identity-to-an-existing-column) solution on SO.

Comment: select into creates a new table. If the table already exists then it could be an issue.

Comment: Yes, I know, but I added one more solution how to create table _correctly_.

Answer (score 9):

```
INSERT INTO NewTable (...,...)
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY order_column), * from SampleTable
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are in SQL Server

```
INSERT INTO newTable (idCol, c1,c2,...cn)
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY c1), c1,c2,...cn
FROM oldTable
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this query to insert 1,2,3... Replace MyTable and ID with your column names.

```
DECLARE @myVar int
SET @myVar = 0
UPDATE
  MyTable
SET
   ID =  @myvar ,
   @myvar = @myVar + 1
```