# Sequence as default value for a column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, sequence

I have already created a sequence:

```
create sequence mainseq as bigint start with 1 increment by 1
```

How do I use this sequence as the default value of a column?

```
create table mytable(
    id      bigint not null default mainseq     -- how?
    code    varchar(20) not null
)
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

It turned out to be easy enough:

```
create table mytable (
    id      bigint not null constraint DF_mytblid default next value for mainseq,
    code    varchar(20) not null
)
```

or if the table is already created:

```
alter table mytable
add constraint DF_mytblid
default next value for mainseq
for id
```

(thank you Matt Strom for the correction!)

Comment: Just as a small note that might be very obvious to some... because it's using `default`, it only applies if you don't provide a value or `null`. Users could still override the auto sequence value by providing a value in their query.

Comment: Is there any way we can enforce use of the default?

Comment: @MattiasNordqvist using [identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property)

Answer (score 13):

The ALTER statement is not quite complete. It needs another FOR clause to assign the default to the desired field.

```
ALTER TABLE mytable
ADD CONSTRAINT DF_mytblid
DEFAULT (NEXT VALUE FOR mainseq) FOR [id]
```

Answer (score -4):

```
create table users(
    u_id int identity(1,1) primary key,
    u_type varchar(30) default 'member', 
    entrydate datetime default (getdate()), 
    updatedate  datetime default (getdate()),
    isactive bit default 1,
    firstname varchar(30),
    lastname varchar(30),
    email varchar(50),
    password varchar(50)
)
```

Comment: And how does your answer show usage of a sequence as column default values?

Comment: This is not a sequence this is the built in Identity.