# How can I insert in Fluent NHibernate using SQL Server 2012 with sequences?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm trying to use SQL Server 2012 + Fluent NHibernate + sequences.
I have a created sequence in SQL Server 2012, I've configured the sequence in my table like in this link [sequence as a default value for a column in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14413383/sequence-as-default-value-for-a-column)
But I'm trying to insert a record and It does not work, I receive the error "null identifier".

Is there any example about how to configure Fluent NHibernate working with SQL Server 2012 sequences?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look a [this site](http://ronaldrosiernet.azurewebsites.net/blog/2013/05/14/setting_a_sequence_as_a_default_value_through_nhibernate), here they use a default sequence.

```
this.Id(x => x.Id)
.GeneratedBy.SeqHiLo("mysequence", "1000")
.Default("next value for mysequence");
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me. I didn't use the SchemaExport and It works :).