# My data-value parameter does not conform to the parameter SQL Server error is: 200 state 7

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ldap, table-valued-parameters

I am attempting to load data from Active Directory users into a table which has additional data in the table.

The table structure is:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[IMS_ADUSER-test2]
(
    [IMSuserID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [EmployID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [DisplayName] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Initials] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [LastName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Email] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [SamAccountName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [DistinguishedName] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [ObjectGUID] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [ObjectSid] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [physicalDeliveryOfficeName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [CreateDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [ModifiedBy] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [UpdateDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [IsDisabled] [bit] NULL,
    [DisabledDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [IMS_USER_ID_FK] [bigint] NULL,
    [AccountClosedDate] [datetime] NULL
)
```

My table type is:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[TestC_IMS_ADUSER_TMP] AS TABLE
(
    [IMSuserID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [EmployID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [DisplayName] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Initials] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [LastName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Email] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [SamAccountName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [DistinguishedName] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [ObjectGUID] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [ObjectSid] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [physicalDeliveryOfficeName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [CreateDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [ModifiedBy] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [UpdateDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [IsDisabled] [bit] NULL,
    [DisabledDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [IMS_USER_ID_FK] [bigint] NULL,
    [AccountClosedDate] [datetime] NULL
)
```

My stored procedure is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TestBulkInsertion-2  
      @datatable TestC_IMS_ADUSER_TMP READONLY 
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO IMS_ADUSER-test2 (IMSuserID, EmployID, DisplayName, FirstName, Initials, LastName, 
                                  Email, SamAccountName, DistinguishedName, ObjectGUID, ObjectSid, 
                                  physicalDeliveryOfficeName, CreateDate, ModifiedBy, UpdateDate, IsDisabled, IMS_USER_ID_FK, AccountClosedDate)
        SELECT 
            NEXT VALUE FOR sequence_test, EmployID, DisplayName, FirstName, Initials, LastName,
            Email, SamAccountName, DistinguishedName, ObjectGUID, ObjectSid, 
            physicalDeliveryOfficeName, GETDATE(), SYSTEM_USER, UpdateDate, IsDisabled, IMS_USER_ID_FK, AccountClosedDate 
        FROM 
            @datatable 
END
```

The error that I am getting is:

> Unhandled Exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Operand type clash: datetime2 is incompatible with bit
>   The data for table-valued parameter "@datatable" doesn't conform to the table type of the parameter. SQL Server error is: 200, state: 7
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
>      at LoadADuserIntoDataBase.DataAccess.DataAccess.InsertADuserTabe(DataTable dt) in c:\users\1089907450e\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\LoadADuserIntoDataBase\LoadADuserIntoDataBase\DataAccess\DataAccess.cs:line 28
>      at LoadADuserIntoDataBase.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\users\1089907450e\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\LoadADuserIntoDataBase\LoadADuserIntoDataBase\Program.cs:line 23

As you can see that the error is stating that my table type has a datetime2 is incompatible with my bit. The SQL Server seems to be solid. I cannot see where the problem is at.

My data access programming is:

```
public  void InsertADuserTabe(DataTable dt)
{
    using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(dbString()))
    {
         var dtAD = dt;
        var cmd = new SqlCommand("TestBulkInsertion-2", con) { CommandType = 
        CommandType.StoredProcedure };
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@datatable", dt));
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

My code is:

```
public static DataTable GetADusers()
{
    try
    {
        string ou = "OU"

        using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, 
       Environment.UserDomainName, ou))
        {
            UserPrincipal user = new UserPrincipal(ctx);
            using (PrincipalSearcher ps = new PrincipalSearcher(user))
            {
                DataTable results = new DataTable();
                results.Columns.Add("EmployeeID");
                results.Columns.Add("DisplayName ");
                results.Columns.Add("FirstName");
                results.Columns.Add("Initial");
                results.Columns.Add("LastName");
                results.Columns.Add("mail");
                results.Columns.Add("SamAccountName");
                results.Columns.Add("DistinguishedName");
                results.Columns.Add("ObjectGUID");
                results.Columns.Add("objectSid");
                results.Columns.Add("physicalDeliveryOfficeName");

                int count = 0;

                foreach (Principal p in ps.FindAll())
                {
                    UserPrincipal u = p as UserPrincipal;
                    if (u != null)
                    {
                        DirectoryEntry entry = 
 (DirectoryEntry)p.GetUnderlyingObject();
                        DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
                        //string query = "(&(objectCategory=person) 
 (objectClass=user)(!(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))(&(mail=*)))";
                        //UAC - CAC Enabled Accounts (no disabled accounts or 
  password never expires) and has a Email Account
                        string query = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user) 
 (!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2) 
 (!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=65536) 
 (userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=262144)(userPrincipalName=1*@mil)(mail=*))";
                        search.Filter = query;
                        search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("EmployeeID");
                        search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("DisplayName");
                        search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("GivenName");
                        search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("Initials");
                        search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sn");
                        search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail");
                        search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("SamAccountName");
                        search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("DistinguishedName");
                        search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("ObjectGUID");
                        search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("objectSid");
                        search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("physicalDeliveryOfficeName");

                        SearchResultCollection mySearchResultColl = search.FindAll();

                        foreach (SearchResult sr in mySearchResultColl)
                        {
                            DataRow dr = results.NewRow();
                            DirectoryEntry de = sr.GetDirectoryEntry();
                            dr["EmployeeID"] = de.Properties["EmployeeID"].Value;
                            dr["DisplayName "] = de.Properties["DisplayName"].Value;
                            dr["FirstName"] = de.Properties["GivenName"].Value;
                            dr["Initial"] = de.Properties["Initials"].Value;
                            dr["LastName"] = de.Properties["sn"].Value;
                            dr["mail"] = de.Properties["mail"].Value;
                            dr["SamAccountName"] = 
  de.Properties["SamAccountName"].Value;
                            dr["DistinguishedName"] = 
  de.Properties["DistinguishedName"].Value;
                            //var GUID = new 
  Guid((byte[])de.Properties["ObjectGUID"].Value);
                            dr["ObjectGUID"] = new 
   Guid((byte[])de.Properties["ObjectGUID"].Value);
                            //var sid = new 
   SecurityIdentifier((byte[])de.Properties["objectSid"].Value, 0);
                            dr["objectSid"] = new 
   SecurityIdentifier((byte[])de.Properties["objectSid"].Value, 0);
                            dr["physicalDeliveryOfficeName"] = 
       de.Properties["physicalDeliveryOfficeName"].Value;
                            //dr["guid"] = de.Properties["guid"].Value;
                            results.Rows.Add(dr);
                            count++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return results;
                //DataView DV = new DataView(results);
                //dgvActiveDirectory.DataSource = DV;
                //lblCount.Text = count.ToString();
            }

        }
    }
    catch (NullReferenceException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("data error" + ex);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        return dt;
    }
}
```

I have a wrapper:

```
public static DataTable AddColumns(DataTable dt)
{
    DataColumn PK = new DataColumn("IMSuserID", typeof(System.Int64));
    DataColumn user = new DataColumn("ModifiedBy", typeof(System.String));
    DataColumn CreateDate = new DataColumn("CreateDate", typeof(System.DateTime));
    //Required Data
    dt.Columns.Add(PK);
    dt.Columns.Add(user);
    dt.Columns.Add(CreateDate);
    //non required data
    DataColumn FK = new DataColumn("IMS_USER_ID_FK", typeof(System.Int64));
    DataColumn Update = new DataColumn("UpdateDate", typeof(System.DateTime));
    DataColumn IsDeleted = new DataColumn("IsDisabled", typeof(System.Boolean));
    DataColumn DisabledDate = new DataColumn("DisabledDate", 
    typeof(System.DateTime));
    DataColumn ClosedDate = new DataColumn("AccountClosedDate", typeof(System.DateTime));
    dt.Columns.Add(FK);
    //FK.DefaultValue = null;
    dt.Columns.Add(Update);
    //Update.DefaultValue = null;
    dt.Columns.Add(IsDeleted);
    //IsDeleted.DefaultValue = null;
    dt.Columns.Add(DisabledDate);
    //DisabledDate.DefaultValue = null;
    dt.Columns.Add(ClosedDate);
    //ClosedDate.DefaultValue = null;
    return dt;
}
```

Implementation is:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
        DataAccess.DataAccess da = new DataAccess.DataAccess();
        //da.InsertADuserTabe(GetADusers());
        da.InsertADuserTabe(AddColumns(GetADusers()));
        Console.WriteLine("Done");
        //DataAccess da = new LoadADuserIntoDataBase.DataAccess();
        //InsertADuserTabe(GetADusers());
}
```

As you can see there does not seem any reason for for the operand type clash datetime2 is incompatible with bit. I am at a stuck point. I would appreciate any help.

I alter the table to add the sequence as a default value:
[Sequence as Default Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14413383/sequence-as-default-value-for-a-column)

I also changed the Stored Procedure to:

```
alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[TestBulkInsertion-2] @datatable TestC_IMS_ADUSER_TMP READONLY AS BEGIN
insert INTO MS_ADUSER-test4
(IMSuserID, EmployID,DisplayName,FirstName,Initials,LastName,Email,SamAccountName,DistinguishedName,ObjectGUID,ObjectSid,physicalDeliveryOfficeName,CreateDate,ModifiedBy,UpdateDate, IsDisabled, IMS_USER_ID_FK,AccountClosedDate )
SELECT  IMSuserID, EmployID,DisplayName,FirstName,Initials,LastName,Email,SamAccountName,DistinguishedName,ObjectGUID,ObjectSid,physicalDeliveryOfficeName,GETDATE(),SYSTEM_USER,UpdateDate, IsDisabled, IMS_USER_ID_FK,AccountClosedDate 
FROM @datatable END
```

As you can see, I replaced the sequence with the actual colomn name in the select query. I get the same error

Comment: The data table columns order must match the table type columns order - even if the names are not the same. Not sure if it's ADO.Net or SQL Server that ignores the column names, but they are parsed by order and not by name.

Comment: Looks like you are missing IMSUserID in the Select. This causes everything to be off by 1. I'm guessing it is trying to put IsDisabled into UpdateDate and it can't parse the bit into a datetime.

Comment: This sounds like it may be the case. I am using a sequence (NEXT VALUE FOR sequence_test) in place for the IMSUserID should that be the correct syntax for adding a sequence if it is it should be the correct place holder. sequence_test is the name of my sequence

Comment: I made some modification replacing the seqence and made it the default value for the column altered the stored procedure I still get the same error.

Comment: Does it matter if the DataTable is out of sequence

Answer (score 0):

I ended up changing the Table Type and Stored procedure.
The Table Type code:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[Test_IMS_ADUSER_TMP] AS TABLE(
[EmployID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[DisplayName] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
[FirstName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Initials] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
[LastName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[mail] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
[SamAccountName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[DistinguishedName] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
[ObjectGUID] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
[ObjectSid] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
[physicalDeliveryOfficeName] [nvarchar](50) NULL)
```

The stored procedure code:

```
CREATE proc [dbo].[TestBulkInsertion-1] @datatable Test_IMS_ADUSER_TMP READONLY as begin insert into IMS_ADUSER([EmployID],[DisplayName],[FirstName],[Initials],[LastName],[Email][SamAccountName],[DistinguishedName],[ObjectGUID],[ObjectSid],[PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName])select EmployID,[DisplayName],[FirstName],[Initials],[LastName][mail],[SamAccountName],[DistinguishedName],[ObjectGUID],[ObjectSid],[PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName]from @datatable end
```

It loaded in the original table. It appears the C# code was fine! I appreciate the help!