# Auto Increment missing

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have imported a table from one database to another, the issue is the auto increment ID has now been removed, I want to add the primary key back to the original column on my copied table and get it working again by taking the last max ID when it was working and continuing to add 1 as normal, is this possible.

Thanks P

Comment: also check - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049210/adding-an-identity-to-an-existing-column

Answer (score 0):

Just Check the Table.Whether Identity is must be there..Remove the identity..So it wil start from 1

The Query
DBCC CHECKIDENT('Your Table Name', RESEED, 0)