# razor set value of variable created by .query() method

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, razor

I have used the following code to get one more than the biggest ID in a table using razor

```
@foreach (var top in db.Query("SELECT MAX(ID)+1 as ID FROM mytable"))
            {
                if (@top.ID == null) {@top.ID = 1; }
            }
```

if the table is empty, @top.ID returns null. I am trying to set its value to 1 if it is null. It however shows an error in the assignment part. How do you assign the value of @top.ID to something else? Or is there a way to user the sql query to set ID as 1 if the table is empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
 select isnull(max(ID),1) from YourTable
```

However, if you're trying to generate a new ID for a new record, you'd be better advised to use an `identity` field.

Comment: I tried identity field with alter table it was showing errors

Comment: sorry did not complete the previous comment

I tried identity field with alter table it was showing errors

ALTER TABLE  tblDDWeatherTimedValues
ALTER COLUMN ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY

it shows me an error at identity
I will however need the above code too some other proposes. And your code works thanks a lot.

Comment: any idea about why my sql query is not working?

ALTER TABLE mytable ALTER COLUMN ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY

Comment: @NevilleNazerane See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049210/adding-an-identity-to-an-existing-column