# SQL Server error: Incorrect syntax near 'MODIFY'. in my query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This is the query that I am trying to execute

```
use [warz]
go

ALTER TABLE dbo.items_lootdata
MODIFY TABLE [RecordID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
go
```

I got the error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>   Incorrect syntax near 'MODIFY'.

Any ideas?

Comment: You want to add a new column or just modifying an existing column?

Comment: `MODIFY` command does not exist in SQL Server. What are  you trying to achieve? Add new column? Alter existing? Add identity?

Comment: You can **(a)** add a new column with `ALTER TABLE ... ADD columnName ....` or **(b)** you can alter a column's definition with `ALTER TABLE ... ALTER COLUMN columnName ....` - but there's no `MODIFY` keyword in SQL Server, nor can you add the `IDENTITY` specification to an existing column.

Comment: uh, my bad, a guy made this for me, i don't use sql server too much i will try this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a new column:

```
use [warz]
go


ALTER TABLE dbo.items_lootdata
ADD [RecordID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
go
```

Modify an existing column:

```
use [warz]
go

-- remember you cannot alter an existing column to
-- identity, following is only for syntax
ALTER TABLE dbo.items_lootdata
ALTER COLUMN [RecordID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
go
```

One thing to note is that altering an existing column and that too in an Identity is rather tricky.

Edit 1: Commenting the `ALTER` syntax to correctly highlight the issue as pointed out by [marc_s](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13302/marc-s)

Relevant solution can be found at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049210/adding-an-identity-to-an-existing-column).

Comment: `ADD COLUMN` in your first code example should just be `ADD`, because MSSQL is sneaky like that.

Comment: You **CANNOT** alter an existing column to add the `IDENTITY` to it - doesn't work. You need to add a **new** column if you want it to be `IDENTITY`

Comment: That is why the note. I knew someone will notice the obvious mistake. That is just there for the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your `MODIFY TABLE` should probably be `ALTER COLUMN` instead.

`IDENTITY` can be a pain, as you're not going to have much luck adding it as a property to a column.  Tables with `IDENTITY` columns need to have them ( the `IDENTITY` columns, that is ) created that way and afterwards it is not easy to get rid of that property either.

Assuming you have a table that is more or less like this:

```
IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT  1
                FROM    sys.objects
                WHERE   name = 'items_lootdata'
                    AND type = 'U' )
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE dbo.items_lootdata
    (                                                   
        RecordID    INTEGER NOT NULL,
        MoreData    BIT
    );
END;
GO
```

If you want the RecordID to be an `IDENTITY` enabled column, if your table is currently empty you can simply recreate the object:

```
    IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT  1
                FROM    sys.objects
                WHERE   name = 'items_lootdata'
                    AND type = 'U' )
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE dbo.items_lootdata
    (                                                   
        RecordID    INTEGER IDENTITY( 1, 1 ) NOT NULL,
        MoreData    BIT
    );
END;
    GO
```

I prefer to perform a meta-data switch if possible, however, as it would also preserve any data currently contained in your table.  This involves a rename, the creation of a new table and the switch itself.  You will probably also want to set the first parameter of your `IDENTITY` column to something greater than or equal to the current maximum value of RecordID as well, as I assume you'll be wanting to put a primary key on that column afterwards.

```
IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT  1
                FROM    sys.objects
                WHERE   name = 'items_lootdata'
                    AND type = 'U' )
BEGIN
    --DROP TABLE dbo.items_lootdata;  
    CREATE TABLE dbo.items_lootdata
    (                                                   
        RecordID    INTEGER NOT NULL, 
        MoreData    BIT
    );

    INSERT INTO dbo.items_lootdata( RecordID, MoreData )
    VALUES( 1, 1 );
END;
GO

EXECUTE dbo.sp_rename @objname = 'dbo.items_lootdata', @newname = 'items_lootdata_old'

IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT  1
                FROM    sys.objects
                WHERE   name = 'items_lootdata'
                    AND type = 'U' )
BEGIN
    --DROP TABLE dbo.items_lootdata;  
    CREATE TABLE dbo.items_lootdata
    (                                                   
        RecordID    INTEGER IDENTITY( 1, 1 ) NOT NULL, 
        MoreData    BIT
    );
END;
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.items_lootdata_old
SWITCH TO dbo.items_lootdata;
GO

DROP TABLE dbo.items_lootdata_old;
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.items_lootdata ( MoreData )
VALUES ( 0 );
GO

SELECT  *
FROM    dbo.items_lootdata;
```

Note that for the `ALTER ... SWITCH` to work, you may have to modify the things you actually *can* sync before trying it.  The `SWITCH` will fail if the structures aren't otherwise identical ( ie: the original RecordID column is nullable ), so those things will need to be addressed.