# Adding sequences when using INSERT INTO command

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to add a large number of rows into a SQL Server table, but I need to sequence the numbers by adding 1 to two columns in the `Insert INTO` command. How can I tell the next line that is added to add one to the previous number for a specific column?

I am trying to add to the `PartID` and `Sequence` columns when the column does not allow duplicate numbers?

The is the query I am using

```
INSERT INTO JobParts(JPListID, PartID, Quantity, ReplacementPercent, Sequence, FlatRateExceptCode, Fluid, Replaced)
VALUES ('1', '670', '1', '100.00', '25', '0', 'False', 'False');
go 50
```

Comment: Which version of SQL Server?

Comment: Hmmm, you are passing in string values for both `PartId` and `Sequence`.  Your request doesn't make sense.

Comment: Ya, those were a starting point. I need to tell PartId and Sequence to add one to the existing number in each of those columns.  I need to start PartId with 670 then increment by 1 each time, and Sequence needs to start with 1 and then increment by 1 each time.

Comment: I am using MSSQL 2008

Comment: I have about 20k lines to add.  All the other fields stay the same numbers.  PartId and Sequence are the only numbers that need to be sequenced

Comment: This is the error I get

Comment: Msg 2601, Level 14, State 1, Line 1
Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.JobParts' with unique index 'IDX_Sequence'.
The statement has been terminated.
** An error was encountered during execution of batch. Continuing.

Comment: `IDENTITY` would be what you are looking for. Can you alter the `JobParts` table? If not you can first insert into a temp table and from there to `JobParts`.

Comment: Please don't use string literals for numbers. `'1'` is a string/character value, `1` is a number.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IDENTITY` property on the column to make SQL Server automatically increment your desired column. Note that you can not add `IDENTITY` to the column after the fact. This has to be done during creation of the table or it can be done by deleting old column and adding new column with `IDENTITY` property.

If you already have date and don't want to lose anything take a look at this questions [Adding an identity to an existing column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049210/adding-an-identity-to-an-existing-column)

Full documentation on `IDENTITY [can be found here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx)