# SQL Server Copy a table from one database to another and retain identity field

Tags: sql-server

I am copying a table from one database to another, actually from one connection to another. The problem is that the key field is an identity field. In the new database in does not the identity property.

So when I try to insert into the new table I get an error because the field which used to have an identity property cannot be null. I could create a new identity field and then rename it to the original name but then the values would be out of sync with the other tables it is link to.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Bob

Comment: Please post your sql.

Comment: Maybe this will work for you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049210/adding-an-identity-to-an-existing-column

Comment: Is both databases on same instance?

Answer (score 0):

The answer can be found in the second comment. I'll paste it here:

CREATE TABLE dbo.Tmp_Names
    (
      Id int NOT NULL
             IDENTITY(1, 1),
      Name varchar(50) NULL
    )
ON  [PRIMARY]
go

SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Tmp_Names ON
go

IF EXISTS ( SELECT  *
            FROM    dbo.Names ) 
    INSERT  INTO dbo.Tmp_Names ( Id, Name )
            SELECT  Id,
                    Name
            FROM    dbo.Names TABLOCKX
go

SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Tmp_Names OFF
go

Answer (score -1):

This will create table `[db2].[dbo].[YoutableNameYouWantInDb2]` in db2 with same structure as in db1 and copy all data from `[db1].[dbo].[yourTableName]`.

```
SELECT * INTO [db2].[dbo].[YoutableNameYouWantInDb2] 
FROM [db1].[dbo].[yourTableName]
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. This didn't work though. Everything is fine except that the new table key doesn't not have the identity property. This is mu problem.