# Add a IDENTITY to a column in SQL SERVER 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
create table stud(
Student_Id int primary key,
Student_Name varchar(30),
Student_surname varchar(12),
Student_Initial varchar(10))
```

I had created a table stud. Now i want to add Identity to Student_Id column using alter query

```
alter table stud alter column student_Id int identity
```

I get error as

Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'identity'.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049210/adding-an-identity-to-an-existing-column

Answer (score 3):

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable
  ADD ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot make an already existing column as an `IDENTITY` column. Either you drop and recreate the table with the column marked as `IDENTITY', or drop the column and add a new`IDENTITY` column.

Answer (score 1):

**Syntax:**

```
IDENTITY [ (seed , increment) ]
```

alter your table like as this:

```
create table stud( 
Student_Id int IDENTITY(1,1) primary key,
Student_Name varchar(30), 
Student_surname varchar(12), 
Student_Initial varchar(10));
```

Answer (score 1):

If Stud contains data, you could always make a shadow table, e.g. Stud2, which contains the Identity column, then run

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.stud SWITCH TO dbo.stud2
```

Then you can reseed Stud2, drop Stud, and rename Stud2 to Stud.

That way you can keep the data while dropping/recreating the table with Identity.

Answer (score 0):

you can use below query to set identity

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[stud](
    [Student_Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Student_Name] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [Student_surname] [varchar](12) NULL,
    [Student_Initial] [varchar](10) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Student_Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO