# Django Unique Image Id Generation

Tags: python, django

I am relatively new in django .I am developing a project using django where i have a  option to upload image.For upload image , i have following model and view

models.py

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'photos', blank=False,null=True)
    approved = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    uploaded_time = models.DateTimeField()
    description = models.CharField(max_length = 80 , blank = False , null = True)
    approved_by = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

views.py

```
def UserImageUpload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, 'Your Image upload is waiting for Admin approval')

            newdoc = Photo(photo = request.FILES['photo'],watermarked_image=request.FILES['photo'],user = request.user,name = request.POST['name'],description = request.POST['description'],uploaded_time=datetime.datetime.now(),Certified=request.POST['Certification'])
            newdoc.save()
        else:
            messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, 'Something is Missing!')

    else:
        form = DocumentForm()

    uploaded_image = Photo.objects.all()

    return render_to_response('myprofile/user_image_upload.html',{'uploaded_image':uploaded_image,'form':form},context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

now i want to create a auto generated **image Id** for every uploaded image. Don't mess up the **image Id** with the **pk** of images.Now the question is, how can i do this.

Comment: Why don't you add an identity column to your DB table, which will auto increment for every new row? And it doesn't need to be a PK

Comment: actually i want to generate an unique image id beside pk of images,its obvious that every image have a pk ,but beside that i also want to generate a image id for every uploaded image.

Comment: its more like an auto  referal code generating.

Comment: I understand and that's exactly what I said in my first comment. You can create an identity column that's not a PK

Comment: can you give it as a answer please? If it works well then i will accept it.

Comment: I strongly recommend using STDimage pip install stdimage its super easy and you do less work. https://github.com/humanfromearth/django-stdimage

Comment: is it useful for generating an unique image id ? @eddwinpaz

Comment: @Tanweer see the documentation. I use it and I've never had problems with duplicate images

Comment: @Tanweer you can also add a tag to the image if needed like _12323123 underscore with a unix timestamp. But this is something that you might want to add and pass it to...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add it as an identity column to your DB table, which will auto increment for every new row. And it doesn't need to be a PK.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049210/adding-an-identity-to-an-existing-column) should help further.