# How to modify a table's column to allow identity on sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

So far I've tried to modify the field with:

```
ALTER TABLE items ALTER COLUMN Item_ID int Identity(1,1)
```

but it doesn't work.

I have done some research on Google, but cannot solve it yet.

Comment: You can't alter the existing columns for identity, check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049210/adding-an-identity-to-an-existing-column

Answer (score 2):

You did not mention that whether the `items` column already exists, or not.  If it does,
you cannot add identity constraint for the existing column.

[read this](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/adding-identity-property-existing-column)

I believe that you have to create a new column using this query:

```
ALTER TABLE items
  ADD Item_ID int IDENTITY (1, 1)
```