# How to remove Identity Specification for Multiple tables at once in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I am having total 109 table in Database and now i am migrating to amazon server with identity insert and now i want to remove auto increment column specification for all tables. How set auto increment column i.e Identity specification to no in SQL server 2008 for all tables.

For Example

I am having

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.tbl_acc
    (
    a1     NUMERIC (18) IDENTITY NOT NULL,
    a2     NUMERIC (18) NULL,
    a3     VARCHAR (4000) NULL,
    a4     VARCHAR (3999) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PK_tbl_acc PRIMARY KEY (a1)
    )
GO
```

And now i would like to remove IDENTITY. Not only for this remaining all tables.

Comment: There is no easy way to remove the identity specification. See the answers here http://stackoverflow.com/a/1730868/73226

Answer (score 0):

Once the `IDENTITY` property is set, it cannot be removed. You can disable it temporarily in a session with `SET IDENTITY_INSERT <table_name> ON/OFF`, but there's no way to permanently convert it back a `numeric` column.

Here's how I did it in similar situations:

1. Drop the primary key constraint
2. Add another `numeric` column to your table (let's call it `a10`) and set its value to that of `a1`
3. Drop `a1`
4. Rename `a10` to `a1`

You can build a dynamic SQL script to do this for all tables. The list of tables can be queried from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`, their constraints from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS`.