# ALTER COLUMN with INTEGER Datatype, NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY, auto increment

Tags: sql-server

I have a MySQL QUERY and working fine.
QUERY IS:

```
ALTER TABLE run 
CHANGE RN_RUN_ID RN_RUN_ID INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
ADD PRIMARY KEY (RN_RUN_ID);
```

I tried to execute same Query and modified in MSSQL which is throwing error.
MSSQL QUERY IS:

```
ALTER TABLE run ALTER COLUMN RN_RUN_ID 
RN_RUN_ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
ADD PRIMARY KEY (RN_RUN_ID);
```

ERROR IS:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'AUTO_INCREMENT'.
```

Can you tell me what I did wrong in this query.

Comment: Come on no googling?Mssql doesnt have auto_increment

Answer (score 0):

You cant do it directly.

See this post: [Adding an identity to an existing column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049210/adding-an-identity-to-an-existing-column)

First answer.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server there is no such `AUTO_INCREMENT` option. Please look at the docs. The equivalent is `IDENTITY`.

You cannot modify a column directly to become IDENTITY. You need to create a new column on the table, or create a new table and rename it. It has some tricky parts (allowing the insert in the identity column, renaming a column, and some other things). [Look this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049210/adding-an-identity-to-an-existing-column#1049305).

There are also differences on the syntax for adding a PK to a table:

```
ALTER TABLE run
ADD CONSTRAINT PK PRIMARY KEY (rn_run_id)
```

If you have acces to SQL Server Management Studio you can get the full script easyly:

- add a new diagram to the database
- add the table to the diagram (rigth click on the window, and use the contextual menu)
- save the diagram (you can delete it later)
- right click on the table and choose custom view
- right click again on the table, and choose "modify custom view". Add the identity, identity initial value, identity increment, key, etc. required elements to the custom view
- modify the column properties in the diagram
- go to the "Table designer" menu, and choose the last option "Generate change scripts". You'll get an script which does all the changes for you. For example:

An example of doing this process (by modifying the column `id` of the table `test`):

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
SET ARITHABORT ON
SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF
SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON
COMMIT
BEGIN TRANSACTION
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.Tmp_test
    (
    id int NOT NULL IDENTITY (10, 2)
    )  ON [PRIMARY]
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.Tmp_test SET (LOCK_ESCALATION = TABLE)
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Tmp_test ON
GO
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM dbo.test)
     EXEC('INSERT INTO dbo.Tmp_test (id)
        SELECT id FROM dbo.test WITH (HOLDLOCK TABLOCKX)')
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Tmp_test OFF
GO
DROP TABLE dbo.test
GO
EXECUTE sp_rename N'dbo.Tmp_test', N'test', 'OBJECT' 
GO
COMMIT
```

*NOTE: the name of the menu options can be different, i don't have an English SSMS at hand right now*

Relevant docs:

- [IDENTITY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx)
- [DBCC CHECKIDENT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx)
- [SET IDENTITY_INSERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188059.aspx)
- [ALTER TABLE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx)