# Subquery returned more than 1 value in SQL SErver 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, scalar-subquery

Please see my previous question that I am still stuck with.    [Insert statement with sub queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28870087/insert-statement-with-sub-queries)

I have 4 columns I need to address and I cannot drop the table to change the 4th column from an int not null to a

I was directed FROM this original statement:

```
INSERT into ADVNET.dbo.KenCatItemTest
(categoryitemid,itemid,categoryid)
SELECT NEWID(),itemid,'0FCA508F-7EB5-4C2E-8803-DE688C4126E5'
FROM janel.dbo.item
WHERE janel.dbo.item.itemnumber like 'c-%' and listprice > 0
```

and it throws error:

Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'LineSequence', table 'ADVNET.dbo.KenCatItemTest'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.

So now I am looking at this statement instead:

```
DECLARE @CategoryItemId uniqueidentifier;  
SET @CategoryItemId = NEWID();  
DECLARE @ItemID uniqueidentifier;  
SET @ItemId = (select itemid from janel.dbo.item
WHERE janel.dbo.item.itemnumber like 'c-%' and listprice > 0 );
DECLARE @CategoryID uniqueidentifier;
SET @CategoryID = '0FCA508F-7EB5-4C2E-8803-DE688C4126E5';
DECLARE @LineSequence int;
SELECT @LineSequence = ISNULL(MAX(LineSequence),0) + 1  
FROM KenCatItemTest WHERE CategoryId = @CategoryId;
INSERT INTO ADVNET.dbo.KenCatItemTest
(CategoryItemId, ItemId, CategoryId, LineSequence)
VALUES (@CategoryItemId, @ItemId, @CategoryId, @LineSequence)
```

this new statement throws the error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
>   Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 5
>   Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ItemId', table 'ADVNET.dbo.KenCatItemTest'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
>   The statement has been terminated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This statement is causing the problem:

```
SET @ItemId = (select itemid from janel.dbo.item
WHERE janel.dbo.item.itemnumber like 'c-%' and listprice > 0 );
```

If there is more than one row which satifies the condition then the error will occur because the `SET` statement expects there to be a scalar value returned on the right side and not a row set.

To fix it you can either narrow down the criteria to where only a single row is returned or do something like pull the first value.

For example:

```
SET @ItemId = (select TOP 1 itemid from janel.dbo.item
WHERE janel.dbo.item.itemnumber like 'c-%' and listprice > 0 );
```

Comment: thank you @Jason-Faulkner.  but how can i accomplish the task of bringing all of the records over and creating all of the rows?

Perhaps I should not be using scalar variables?

Comment: @KEN - Easist way would be to use a `CURSOR`. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx

Comment: No need for a cursor to do inserts. I don't see anything in the code from the OP that would suggest any kind of looping is needed.

Comment: @SeanLange - The `LineSequence` appears to have to be manually incremented for each row. Other than this, a `SELECT INTO` could be used.

Comment: Sure incrementing numbers is painless using ROW_NUMBER or even a tally table. No need to resort to looping.

Answer (score 1):

Can you not just use Row_number() to generate a value for LineSequence?

```
    INSERT INTO ADVNET.dbo.KenCatItemTest(
           categoryitemid
          ,itemid
          ,categoryid
          ,LineSequence)
    SELECT 
           NEWID()
          ,itemid
          ,'0FCA508F-7EB5-4C2E-8803-DE688C4126E5'
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ItemId)
      FROM 
           janel.dbo.item i
     WHERE 
           i.itemnumber LIKE 'c-%' 
       AND listprice > 0
```