# How to make an existing column primary key and auto increment in sql?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sqlcommand

I have a column named `FinderLogId` in a table named `FinderLog`.

I wanna make it primary key and auto increment. What I tried is the following:

```
ALTER TABLE [gheymatyab.com_db].[dbo].[FinderLog] 
   ALTER COLUMN [FinderLogId] int NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
```

And what I see in the result is this:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IDENTITY'.

Whats the problem?

Comment: At a guess... that should be `IDENTITY(1,1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question looks very similar to this issue:

[Adding an identity to an existing column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049210/adding-an-identity-to-an-existing-column)

You'll either need to add a new primary key column, or else create a new table.  The linked question goes into specifics.