# Trying to insert in a table with primary key autoincrement but getting an error

Tags: sql-server

```
INSERT INTO Locality(versionNo,localityName, localityType, constiCode, deleteFlag,
    createdOn, lastUpdate,updatedBy) 
SELECT 1, localityName, Localitytype, constituencyCode + '' + regionCode, 1,
    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_USER
FROM dbo.MasterTable.

Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'localityCode', table 'GovMaster.dbo.Locality';
column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
```

I want to insert but the LocalityCode is primary key and should not be null. But I get that error above. The localityCode is primary key and it can not be null. And i want the localityCode to be auto generated, it should do an autoincrement on insert.

Comment: The error message states that you're trying to put a null value into the `localityCode` column. Either fix your code to not supply null values for that column or update your DB schema to allow nulls there.

Comment: tags mismatch: you are dealing with mysql or microsoft sql server? also have a look to the [ask howto](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) about guidelines on writing good questions

Comment: Why not Postgres?  We don't know _what_ this guy is using.

Comment: localityCode is a primary key and supposed not to take null values, but I have set the primary key to is-identity to allow autoincrement. But still getting that error. @BenN

Comment: Yes microsoft sql server @Paolo

Comment: so modify the question and put correct tags. also add some relevant detail to the question because it is almost empty...

Comment: Could you do a CREATE TABLE script on the table in question?  It might have the Is-Identity property set correctly but missing the Increment and Seed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not inserting a value for `localityCode`, it's missing from your field list:

```
INSERT INTO Locality(versionNo,localityName, localityType, constiCode, deleteFlag,
    createdOn, lastUpdate,updatedBy)
```

When you leave a field off the `INSERT` list, it gets a default `NULL` value. If it were an auto-incrementing ID field, it would be correct to exclude it, but it is not in your case.  You either need to supply a value, or change the schema to allow `NULL` values for that field, or make it an auto-incrementing field.

Comment: How do I set value to auto increment in microsoft sql server, because I have set it to yes in identity specification, identity increment is 1?!

Comment: Nice catch!  Sharp eye.

Comment: `localityCode  INT IDENTITY(1,1),` should do it, odd if yours is set that way already.

Answer (score 0):

Just cutting to the chase, the reason you are getting that error is because:

**Problem:**

- You have a column name `localityCode` defined as a `NOT NULL` in your Locality table and it does not appear to be an auto-incrementing field.
- Secondly, you are not passing any value in your insert statement below, hence it's passing a null value by default to your `localityCode` column.

**Solution:**

- Ideally, you would want to pass some non-null values to your `localityCode` explicitly in your insert statement.
- The other option would be change your null property for your `localityCode` column to accept `NULL` values.
- Alternatively, if you want to set the `localityCode` column as an auto-increment field, you may want to look into this: [Adding an identity to an existing column](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1049305/1821329)

Hope this helps!

Comment: The localityCode is primary key and it can not be null. And i want the localityCode to be auto generated, it should do an autoincrement. @Futbolfan

Comment: @user2271980 The answer given by Hart & Co. appears to be spot on.  Please have a look at that.

Comment: @user2271980 I think you have two options: either recreate the table and set the `localityCode` identity property on OR add a new column and set that as your primary key with identity property and drop this existing column.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys.

I dropped the existing column and recreated it with *localityCode INT IDENTITY(1,1)* and alter the column to primary key after that.

:-)

Comment: Ideally, in SO you would want to post your own answer as a solution only if nobody had provided any direction. If someone has taken their `valuable` time to respond to your question correctly, it is a common courtesy in SO to either accept their solution as the accepted answer or upvote (or both in most cases).

Comment: Please pardon me, i'm quite not a common user on this platform. I will do so next time. Some features are not going through due to my current status. @FutbolFan. Thanks

Comment: I think @HartCO deserves a big credit as well for pointing you to the right direction. And, I can definitely understand that your reputation level has some restrictions at the moment.