# django.db.utils.DatabaseError: ORA-30673: column to be modified is not an identity column

Tags: python, django, oracle

thanks everybody, 
I have a django project, this is my enviroment:

**Database**:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

**Python**:
Python 3.5.1rc1
cx-Oracle==6.3
Django==2.0.4

I am trying this:

```
 python manage.py test
```

I am getting this error:

```
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: ORA-30673: column to be modified is not an identity column
```

Thanks.

Comment: You should provide your code.

Comment: Check this. https://stackoverflow.com/q/34972855/6327676

Answer (score 4):

It appears that you are trying to set a column to be the identity column, using the ALTER TABLE command. Oracle, however, tells you that you can't do that.

An example:

Create a table:

```
create table test (id number);
```

This command raises the ORA-30673:

```
alter table test modify id number generated by default on null as identity;
```

You should create a new identity column:

```
alter table test add id_new number generated by default on null as identity;
```

Then *copy* data into a new column, if necessary:

```
update test set id_new = id;
```

Drop the old ID column:

```
alter table test drop column id;
```

Rename the new column to the old name:

```
alter table test rename column id_new to id;
```

Expect problems if the old ID column was a primary key, used in enforcing foreign key constraint(s).

Comment: hi!!, thanks for your answer, I did the example that do you show me, I understand the exception from database perspective but I don´t know if the problem is from django. 

I created a new project but I can´t do the migrate step.

Regards