# Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table when player is created

Tags: sql, sql-server

I get the following error message:

```
{returnResult=Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'player' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.;Result=Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'player' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.;}
```

I'm currently trying to auto-increment a player_id in a player table every time a new player is created. I set this up in Windows SQL Server Management Studio.

What should my query look like?

```
INSERT INTO player (player_id, player_type_id)
VALUES('','1')
```

I have one manual value, but I want the user_id to be unique each time it is created. All help greatly appreciated!

Comment: MYSQL, or SQL Server?

Comment: Sorry, it would be SQL server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have correctly set the `player_id` field up to auto increment, you simply leave that column out of your `INSERT` statement, and just supply the other values.

```
INSERT INTO player (player_type_id)
VALUES('1')
```

If you believe your column is not currently set to auto increment, have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049210/adding-an-identity-to-an-existing-column).

Comment: This worked perfectly. I wasn't sure about leaving the auto-incremented column blank. Thanks! Now I wonder how I would query this player_id without explicitly calling the value.

Comment: No problem, could you elaborate or ask a new question, I'm not sure what you mean by that?

Comment: Sure, I posted it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36772776/find-a-value-based-on-the-most-recently-created-row-in-a-table-sql-server

Answer (score 1):

You have to set identity insert on (that is if you want to supply your own identity value instead of asking MYSQL to generate one for you )

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Table1 ON
```

Then execute your query..by supplying your own value for that column

and then turn it off after that..(Since you want only one manual insert done)

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Table1 OFF
```