# Find a value based on the most recently created row in a table (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server

This potentially might be too large of a question for a complete solution, and I've got a bit of a strange set up. I'm using HP OO to create a text-based RPG just to practice getting used to database design on this platform.

So it's basically a flow script that runs once. When the script starts, a player (user) is created, and then a character is created. The player inputs a name for its character, and this is stored in the `character` table. I then call that character name with `SELECT name FROM character WHERE character.character_id=x`. How can I retrieve the name from the correct (most recently created) character. The `character_id` is an auto-incrementing identity column.

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: I updated it to ask a question.

Comment: Is character_id an IDENTITY column?

Comment: Yes it is. It auto-increments.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to get identity of inserted row?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42648/best-way-to-get-identity-of-inserted-row)

Comment: Yes, that would be the case. And this works okay: ``SELECT name FROM character WHERE character.character_id=IDENT_CURRENT('character')``

Comment: Usint IDENT_CURRENT is not a good approach. If you have multiple people creating new rows you can very easily get the wrong value. SCOPE_IDENTITY is much better for this kind of thing.

Comment: Yep, makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing *guaranteeing* that the highest value in an identity column is the most recently created record.  You should add a `date_created` column to your table and give it a default value of the current date and time (`current_timestamp` for a `datetime2` field).  That actually does what you want.

OK, your question changed a bit and, Tab's comment here is also correct.  If you want to insert and get the identity inserted back, you should follow [the advice here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42648/best-way-to-get-identity-of-inserted-row) that he linked.

However, if you want to be able to determine *the order of creation* -- which is what you originally asked -- then you should use a `date_created` field.  It's possible to get around `IDENTITY` and insert any value you want, and things like UPDATEs and DELETEs can change things as well.  Essentially, it's a bad idea to assign meaning to a record's value of an IDENTITY column relative to other records in the table (i.e., this was created before or after these other records) because you can actually get around that.

Personally, I would either use the `OUTPUT` clause to have my INSERTs send the ID back:

```
INSERT INTO Character (...)
OUTPUT INSERTED.Id
VALUES (....);
```

Or I'd reuse the same connection and return the `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`.

```
INSERT INTO Character (...)
VALUES (....);

SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS [SCOPE_IDENTITY];
```

Comment: Scope_Identity is actually safer if concurrency can be an issue.

Comment: Is the time stamp an identity column? Should I set it to be?

Comment: @bluemunch No, only integers can be IDENTITY columns.  And *do not* use the creation timestamp as a unique identifier, and certainly not as a primary key.  That's a nightmare.

Comment: @TabAlleman I agree.  The question is clearer now than it was.

Comment: Okay, so then in the context of this question specifically (one-time executed flow script), the correct approach would be ``SELECT name FROM character WHERE character.character_id=IDENT_CURRENT('character')``? Since there is no concurrency, and only one user, choosing the most recently created character_id by identity is the way to do it? Seems to work!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT row FROM table WHERE id=(
    SELECT max(id) FROM table
    )
this should work
```

Make sure the id is unique (auto increments? great!)

Answer (score 0):

When you insert into the character table, you should rely on `Scope_Identity()` or `@@Identity` (depending on how your database is setup. Read more about it [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/103610/Difference-between-IDENTITY-SCOPE-IDENTITY-IDENT-C)) to return the unique ID (the auto incremented ID) from the table, and use that moving forward.

Doing it any other way opens you up to data integrity issues.