# Adding Identity to existing column with data in Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, identity

I have a table with 4 million records. I want to change `orderid` to `Identity` without losing the data.

Is it possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049210/adding-an-identity-to-an-existing-column

Comment: See the second answer in the dupe. This is the lowest impact method.