# How to tell the primary key 'Id' of IdentityUser class is IDENTITY(1,1)?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity

I have changed the type of primary key of IdentityUser class from string to int following [this](https://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/change-primary-key-for-users-in-aspnet-identity).

Now when I go to insert data in User table, it wants data for Id field. But I want that the value in Id field will be automatically created by Identity.

In server explorer when I open table definition, it shows

```
[Id] INT NOT NULL
```

but I think it should be

```
[Id] INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
```

So what should I do to make

```
[Id] INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049210/adding-an-identity-to-an-existing-column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)` attribute on your `Id` field:

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public Guid Id { get; set; }
```

and then add an EF migration - it will change the ID field to be auto-incremented.