# how to change department id primary key to identity and do migration to database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first, entity-framework-migrations

**Problem**

I need to modify class Department to make Department ID identity then make affect by migrations to database sql server 2005 .

**What I Try**

I changed [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)] from None to identity .

then from console write enable-migrations but it give me message

Migrations have already been enabled in project 'University Data'. To overwrite

the existing migrations configuration, use the -Force parameter.I also using

-Force but no any result or changed happened .

**my class Department**

```
[Table("Department")]
public partial class Department      { 
public Department()   
{    
}   
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)] 
[Key] 
public int DepartmentID { get; set; } 
public string DepartmentName { get; set; }  

  } 
 }
```

I have class department inside container Containerclass as following :

```
public partial class ContainerClass : DbContext     
 { 
public ContainerClass() : base("name=mycon")      
 {   
 }   
public virtual DbSet Departments { get; set; } 
 }
```

Table department already created in database.

**update**

i write also in console

update-database
but also nothing changed

**update2**

add-migration Department
but also nothing changed column DepartmentID not changed to identity

**update3**

i add migration then write in up() and down()

```
AlterColumn("dbo.Department", "DepartmentID", c => c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true));
```

but it not change column to identity

Comment: Can any one help me if possible

Comment: Are i must remove migaration exist before to do any update in database

Comment: You don't generate migrations with `Enable-Migrations`, you do it with `Add-Migration`. `Enable-Migrations` is meant to be executed only once at the beginning of the life of the project, usually right after your `DbContext` is first created.

Comment: OK how i do by add-migration meaning i write add-migration only

Comment: I write in console add-migration Department but nothing changed to identity

Comment: You can't change a column to identity column in Sql Server. http://stackoverflow.com/q/1049210/861716