# INSERT does not work now that I have Identity Column

Tags: javascript, php, sql-server, identity-column

I have an HTML Table that has an insert button. This used to work just fine. However, I needed my first column to be an Identity column. So after setting one of the columns, MR_ID, as an Identity, my script no longer inserts into the table and database. In the console, it says "row failed to insert" when it used to say "row inserted" before this column was set to Identity. Can someone please tell me what is going on here? I have a lot of code but I want to make sure I post what is necessary to figure out the problem.

Dialog box and table that is being looped in:

```
<div id="dialog-form" title="Add Vendor">
  <p class="validateTips">All form fields are required.</p>

<!-- Dialog box displayed after add row button is clicked -->
  <form>
    <fieldset>
      <label for="mr_name">Vendor</label>
      <input type="text" name="mr_name" id="mr_name" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" value="test">
      <label for="buyer_id">Buyer ID</label>
      <input type="text" name="buyer_id" id="buyer_id" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" value="99">
      <label for="poc_n">POC Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="poc_n" id="poc_n" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" value="name">
      <label for="poc_p">POC Email</label>
      <input type="text" name="poc_e" id="poc_e" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" value="test@tst.com">
      <label for="poc_p">POC Phone</label>
      <input type="text" name="poc_p" id="poc_p" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" value="5555555555">

      <!-- Allow form submission with keyboard without duplicating the dialog button -->
      <input type="submit" id="submit" tabindex="-1" style="position:absolute; top:-1000px">
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>



<div id="users-contain" class="ui-widget">  
<table id="html_master" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content">
<thead>
    <tr class="ui-widget-header">
    <td>ID</td>
    <td>Vendor</td>
    <td>Buyer ID</td>
    <td>POC Name</td>
    <td>POC Email</td>
    <td>POC Phone</td>
    <td>Edit</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>


<?php
    /* Foreach loop that brings in information to populate table */
    foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $rows){
    ?>
    <tr id="<?php echo intval ($rows['MR_ID'])?>">
        <td class="mr_id" id="<?php echo intval ($rows['MR_ID'])?>" contenteditable="false"><?php echo intval ($rows['MR_ID'])?></td>
        <td class="mr_name" id="mr_name-<?php echo intval ($rows['MR_ID'])?>" name="field" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_Name']?></td>
        <td class="buyer_id" id="buy_id<?php echo intval ($rows['MR_ID'])?>" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['Buyer_ID']?></td>
        <td class="poc_n" id="poc_n-<?php echo intval ($rows['MR_ID'])?>" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_POC_N']?></td>     
        <td class="poc_e" id="poc_e-<?php echo intval ($rows['MR_ID'])?>" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_POC_E']?></td>
        <td class="poc_p" id="poc_p-<?php echo intval ($rows['MR_ID'])?>" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_POC_P']?></td>
        <td><input type="button" class="edit" name="edit" value="Edit">
    </tr>
 <?php
  }
 ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
// ----- Dialog Box for adding a row -----

$( function() {   

    var dialog, form,

      emailRegex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/,
      phoneRegex = /^(?:(?:\+?1\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?)?(?:\(\s*([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9])\s*\)|([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9]))\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?)?([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-9]1|[2-9][02-9]{2})\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?([0-9]{4})(?:\s*(?:#|x\.?|ext\.?|extension)\s*(\d+))?$/,
      mr_name = $( "#mr_name" ),
      buyer_id = $( "#buyer_id" ),
      poc_n = $( "#poc_n" ),
      poc_e = $( "#poc_e" ),
      poc_p = $( "#poc_p" ),
      allFields = $( [] ).add( mr_name ).add( buyer_id ).add( poc_n ).add( poc_e ).add( poc_p ),
      tips = $( ".validateTips" );
  console.log(allFields);

    function updateTips( t ) {
      tips
        .text( t )
        .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" );
      setTimeout(function() {
        tips.removeClass( "ui-state-highlight", 1500 );
      }, 500 );
    }

    function checkRegexp( o, regexp, n ) {
      if ( !( regexp.test( o.val() ) ) ) {
        o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
        updateTips( n );
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }

   function addVendor() {
      var valid = true;
      allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
// ----- Validation for each input in add row dialog box -----
      valid = valid && checkRegexp( mr_name, /^[a-z]([0-9a-z_\s])+$/i, "Please enter a valid vendor name" );
      valid = valid && checkRegexp( buyer_id, /^(0|[1-9][0-9]*)$/, "Please enter a valid Buyer ID" );
      valid = valid && checkRegexp( poc_n, /^[a-zA-Z ]*$/, "Please enter a valid name" );
      valid = valid && checkRegexp( poc_e, emailRegex, "Please enter a valid email" );
      valid = valid && checkRegexp( poc_p, phoneRegex, "Please enter a valid phone number" );
      console.log(allFields);
      if ( valid ) {
        var $tr = $( "#html_master tbody tr" ).eq(0).clone();
        var dict = {};
        var errors = "";
        $.each(allFields, function(){
          $tr.find('.' + $(this).attr('id')).html( $(this).val()+"-"+buyer_id );
          var type = $(this).attr('id');
          var value = $(this).val();
          console.log(type + " : " + value);
          // ----- Switch statement that provides validation for each table cell -----
          switch (type) {
             case "mr_id":
                dict["MR_ID"] = value;
              break;
            case "mr_name":
                dict["MR_Name"] = value;
              break;
            case "buyer_id":
                dict["Buyer_ID"] = value;
              break;
            case "poc_n":
                dict["MR_POC_N"] = value;
              break;
            case "poc_e":
                dict["MR_POC_E"] = value;
                break;
            case "poc_p":
                dict["MR_POC_P"] = value;
                break;
            }
        });
        console.log(dict);
        $tr.find('.mr_id').html( $( "#html_master tbody tr" ).length + 1 );
        $( "#html_master tbody" ).append($tr);
        dialog.dialog( "close" );


        var request = $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "insert-copy.php",
          data: dict
        });

        request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
          if(JSON.parse(response) == true){
            console.log("row inserted");
          } else {
            console.log("row failed to insert");
            console.log(response);
          }
        });

        // Callback handler that will be called on failure
        request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            console.error(
                "The following error occurred: "+
                textStatus, errorThrown
            );
        });

        // Callback handler that will be called regardless
        // if the request failed or succeeded
        request.always(function () {

        });


      }
      return valid;
    }

    var dialog = $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      height: 400,
      width: 350,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Add Row": addVendor,
        Cancel: function() {
          dialog.dialog( "close" );
        }
      },
      close: function() {
        form[ 0 ].reset();
        allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
      }
    });

    form = dialog.find( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
      event.preventDefault();
      addVendor();
    });

    $( ".create-user" ).button().on( "click", function() {
      dialog.dialog({
          position: ['center', 'top'],
          show: 'blind',
          hide: 'blind'
      });
      dialog.dialog("open");
    });
  });
```

Insert into table function along with Ajax script:

```
 function insertIntoTable() {

    var tableName = document.getElementById("tableNameInput").value;

    var dict = { tableName: tableName, mrName: 'Temp Object' };

    request = $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "insert-copy.php",
      data: dict
    });

    request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
      if(JSON.parse(response) == true){
        console.log("row inserted");
      } else {
        console.log("row failed to insert");
      }
    });

    // Callback handler that will be called on failure
    request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        // Log the error to the console
        console.error(
            "The following error occurred: "+
            textStatus, errorThrown
        );
    });

    // Callback handler that will be called regardless
    // if the request failed or succeeded
    request.always(function () {

    });

  }



<?php

  $MR_ID = $_POST['MR_ID'];
  $MR_Name = $_POST['MR_Name'];
  $Buyer_ID = $_POST['Buyer_ID'];
  $MR_POC_N = $_POST['MR_POC_N'];
  $MR_POC_E = $_POST['MR_POC_E'];
  $MR_POC_P = $_POST['MR_POC_P'];

  $host="xxxxxxxxxxx"; 
  $dbName="xxxxxx"; 
  $dbUser="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; 
  $dbPass="xxxxxxxxx";

  $pdo = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=".$host.";Database=".$dbName, $dbUser, $dbPass);

  $sql = "INSERT INTO Stage_Rebate_Master (MR_ID, MR_Name, Buyer_ID, MR_POC_N, MR_POC_E, MR_POC_P) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
  $result = $stmt->execute(array($MR_ID, $MR_Name, $Buyer_ID, $MR_POC_N, $MR_POC_E, $MR_POC_P));
  echo json_encode($result);

?>
```

Comment: Can you post the structure of your `Stage_Rebate_Master` table please?

Comment: Did you add the new column to the table as well as the screen

Comment: @KevinStich the table has 6 columns...MR_ID(int, not null), MR_NAME(nvarchar(255), null), BUYER_ID(int, null), MR_POC_N(varchar(25), null), MR_POC_E(varchar(25), null), MR_POC_P(varchar(25), null).......is that what you were looking for?

Comment: @RiggsFolly what exactly do you mean by that? I was able to edit the column so that it was (int, not null) through the SQLPro Studio application.

Comment: Where's the input field for `MR_ID`?

Comment: @JimmyB I do not want there to be an input for the MR_ID...it is set as an Identity so it should be auto incremented...MR_ID is a lookup so I wouldnt want users being able to decide what it should be. Since it is set as an Identity, that allows it to not be null or have a duplicate value.

Comment: Then `$MR_ID = $_POST['MR_ID'];` is not what you want.

Comment: @JimmyB Yeah, But even with taking that out and taking it out of my query and execute statement, I still get the exact same thing.

Comment: If your ID values are auto-generated by the RDBMS, then you *must not* insert them. If you just have an `int, not null` column, that's *not* an identity column and you will have to generate new IDs yourself in PHP (`SELECT max(MR_ID) + 1 ...`).

Comment: your MR_ID is not auto_increment, identity is one thing, auto_increment is another thing. Also, as @JimmyB said, get rid of MR_ID from your sql query.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049210/adding-an-identity-to-an-existing-column

Comment: Are you forgetting to set IDENTITY_INSERT to ON?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188059.aspx

Comment: I went ahead and just created another column called "ID" and made sure it was an identity column...then I turned on identity_insert....so what would be the next step?

Comment: The MR_ID column was actually just int, not null and not identity like @leo_ap mentioned

Comment: Please provide the (current) DDL of the table so that we can see what the `ID` column really is now.

Comment: This is what i used to create the ID column just now...`ALTER TABLE stage_Rebate_Master ADD ID integer identity not null;`

Comment: And you already did remove the `$MR_ID`, the `MR_ID` column in the `INSERT` statement and the corresponding binding parameter `?` from your PHP script? I think it should work then.

Comment: @JimmyB Yes I did, but it still doesnt insert anything

Comment: I suggest you start debugging your `INSERT` statement outside of PHP, to see if and why it fails.

Answer (score 0):

Gathering up the comments:

- You have a `not null` constraint on your `MR_ID` column, so you cannot insert `null` values.
- If you don't want the user to provide the ID, you (PHP) or the database must generate the values for the non-null column.
- If you have an auto-increment column, the value will be automatically generated by the database and you *must not* insert into that column. (Except when identity insert is on, but you should not do that.)
- If your column is not auto-increment, then you must make sure that in every insert you include a non-null integer value.
- If your column is also *unique*, make sure you only try to insert new values.