# Set IDENTITY to existing column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, identity-column, alter-column

I have a table which is having a column name ID field of integer type. It was declared IDENTITY. And it has data according to IDENTITY. But recently I removed IDENTITY column from that table. Now I want to change that to IDENTITY again. But this query says incorrect syntax

```
Alter table FuleConsumptions alter column  TransactionID INT IDENTITY(1,1);
```

But I can perform the same task using SQL server designer in properties of the table.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You cannot do this - just isn't possible. You must create a **new column** and add `IDENTITY` to it

Comment: You'll need an extra table to make it work. See the first two answers to this question (depending on the size of your data set). [Adding an identity to an existing column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049210/adding-an-identity-to-an-existing-column)

Answer (score 0):

I think The identity column will hold the sequence of number thats why it thrown error
better you drop column then create it again and set IDENTITY

```
Alter Table FuleConsumptions Drop Column TransactionID
Go
ALTER TABLE FuleConsumptions
ADD TransactionID int; 
go
Alter table FuleConsumptions alter column  TransactionID INT IDENTITY(1,1);
```

Comment: Is there anyway that I can do it without losing current data of the column?

Comment: @chathwind in that case you can't start from 1 you may where it end