# How do I create a simple index column in a table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, indexing

I've been having trouble figuring out how to add a simple integer-index column to an existing table in a SQL Server database. The [closest question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049210/adding-an-identity-to-an-existing-column) I've been able to find on StackOverflow isn't as simple as my question.

I'm trying to figure out how to turn this:

[image]

into an actual column.

I've seen this:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_SomeColumn
ON SomeTable (SomeColumn);
```

but I do not understand the significance of the `SomeColumn` reference and the database is shared so I don't have much leeway to test.

Comment: You want a row number? Does it need to be stored in the table? Or just displayed when you query the table?

Comment: Stored in the table

Comment: Do you care what order its allocated in?

Comment: `alter table TableName add ColumnName int identity(1,1)` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Do you mean you need a Row Number column? Like the one, you highlighted in the picture? If so, you may take a look at Row_Number() function https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding an identity to an existing column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049210/adding-an-identity-to-an-existing-column)

Comment: @GMB - My question is more rudimentary than the question you're citing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you need new column populated with id.

```
DECLARE @id INT 
SET @id = 0 
UPDATE YourTable
SET @id = ID_COL = @id + 1 
GO
```

then you need to create index on it

```
CREATE INDEX idx_Id_Col
ON YourTable (Id_Col);
```