# Unable to insert values into SQL Server table

Tags: c#, sql-server

When creating an account, values cannot be inserted and error shows that column (`PatronID`), which is the primary key, does not allow nulls. Hence, the `INSERT` fails

Have tried going into the SQL Server table designer to change "Is Identity", but I am unable to save the changes

```
public int add() 
{
    string strConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BABAFOODSConnectionString"].ToString();

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConn);

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Patron (PatronName, PatronEmail, PatronPassword)" +
                                    "OUTPUT INSERTED.PatronID " +
                                    "VALUES(@name, @email, @password)", conn);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", PatronName);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", PatronEmail);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", PatronPassword);

    conn.Open();
    int id = (int) cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    conn.Close();

    return id;
}
```

At the `ExecuteScalar`, I get this error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'PatronID', table 'BABAFOODS.dbo.Patron'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.'

Comment: as the error says: *Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'PatronID', table 'BABAFOODS.dbo.Patron'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails* the column is set to NOT NULL and you are trying to insert `NULL`

Comment: Please show your table definition.

Comment: Make sure it set to `primary key` and `identity (1,1)`

Comment: Unrelated tips: SqlConnection and SqlCommand are both IDisposable so each should be in a `using` block. Once you've done that, you don't need to Close the connection because it will be closed by the implicit Dispose as it exits the block. You may want to read [can we stop using AddWithValue](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).

Comment: @PrashantPimpale where can I set the identity?

Comment: If the column is *not* defined as identity, but as `NOT NULL`, then **you MUST** provide a value from your C# code. And you **cannot** change the identity flag on an existing column - you can only **create** a new column which is defined as identity, and then make that the primary key.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding an identity to an existing column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049210/adding-an-identity-to-an-existing-column)

Answer (score -1):

Just use auto increment on your ID for your table.

Look https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp

Comment: This answer is basically link only. And the OP is on SQL Server not MySQL so the link isn't even relevant

Comment: Not a link only, i explain his problem. And the link is about multiple type SGBD, read better before critics and note for Nothing...