# Alter sql server table Issue

Tags: sql-server

I already created table in database. Now, I need to add "Identity" Column. Please suggest.

```
Create Cus(id int Pk,Name varchar2(50),Age int);

insert into Cus(id,Name,Age) values (1,'abc',12);
// here i need to add "Identity"
alter table Cus alter column id Identity(1,1)
```

Comment: This has been asked before:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049210/adding-an-identity-to-an-existing-column

Comment: And: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/23816.how-to-convert-int-column-to-identity-in-the-ms-sql-server.aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding an identity to an existing column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049210/adding-an-identity-to-an-existing-column)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use Alter command to add an identity to the table.

Answer (score 1):

Here, you need to create dummy column and drop existing one.

```
Create table Cus(id int ,[Name] varchar(50),Age int);

insert into Cus(id,[Name],Age) values (1,'abc',12);

Alter Table Cus Add dummyid int identity(1,1)

Alter Table Cus Drop Column id

Exec sp_rename 'Cus.dummyid ', 'id', 'Column'
```

Comment: Thank you,  "id" i already used as Foriegn Key with out deleting if possible

Comment: well you need to delete data on foreign tables, no way you can do this.

Comment: it is production for clients creating issue

Comment: you can read about UPDATE CASCADE, cant give you the scripts because, i don't have info your foreign tables

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot make any column identity after creating from the query.

You have 2 options, either make it from `SQL Management Studio` or Create another column and copy with identity .

From `Management Studio`.

Step 1: Select Table design.
[image]

Step 2: Change Column properties. 
[image]

Step 3: Save

**Or**

You need to create new column with identity.

1. Create column with identity `Alter table Tablename add newcol int identity(1,1)
2. Then copy your data from previous column to this column by setting `Identity_Insert ON`.
3. Then drop your previous column.
4. After that change column name by using `sp_rename`.

Note: But this will change the ordinal position of your column.

**ANOTHER OPTION**

1. Create new table with similar structure just make your column
   identity whichever you want to be.
2. Copy data from your old table to new table.
3. Drop old table.
4. Change name of new table with old table.

Edit:

**For case of Foreign Key relationship**

If they are not so many and feasible, then you may drop the constraint.

```
ALTER TABLE Yourtable
DROP FOREIGN KEY FK_PersonOrder;
```

Then follow the above steps and recreate them at the last.

```
ALTER TABLE Yourtable
ADD FOREIGN KEY (yourid) REFERENCES Persons(PersonID);
```

Comment: Thank you,  "id" i already used as Foreign Key with out deleting if possible

Comment: you choose first option, using `management studio' only, or you may drop the constraint, then follow the steps.

Answer (score 0):

**Finally i got Solution,**

I added new column in 'Cus' table.

**alter table Cus add tempCusId int identity;**

i removed FK relation in User's Table

and i updated identity values in User Table

***update user set id=1 where id= 1;***

I Compared Id and TempCusId.  After update I removed "Pk" relation in Cus table droped Column "Id",i made "TempCusId" as a "Pk" and identity. Finally User table it self "Id" Column I made FK relation.

And if u have multiple values there than go for a "While" loop

DECLARE @NumberofRowint int=30;

DECLARE @inirow INT=23;
Declare @Grade int ;

WHILE @inirow<= @NumberofRow
BEGIN
DECLARE @ProductID INT=(select Id from [Cus] where id=@inirow)

Set @Grade=(select id from Cus where id=@ProductID)

IF(@Grade= @inirow)
BEGIN
updatetbl_Users set Id=@inirow where id=@ProductID
END

SET @inirow = @inirow + 1;
END;