# Copy IDENTITY column from another table and generate new IDs for missing records

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to copy identity column from one table to another, but I'm getting this error:

> Cannot update identity column 'ID'.

I tried following code:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TableA]
    ADD [ID] INT IDENTITY(20000,1), -- MAX(TableB.Id) < 20000

SET IDENTITY_INSERT TableA ON

UPDATE TableA 
SET TableA.[ID] = TableB.[ID]
FROM TableA 
INNER JOIN TableB ON TableB.ID = TableA.ID

SET IDENTITY_INSERT TableA OFF;
```

**Scenario**

I have two tables with 1:0-1 relationship.

```
TableA: Code (PK)
A,
B,
C,
D

TableB: Id (PK), Code (Unique)
1, A
2, B
3, D
```

**Question**

How to

1. Create new identity column `TableA.Id`
2. Copy values from `TableB.Id`
3. Ensure new unique values for `TableA.Id` if it was missing in `TableB.Id`

Comment: As the error tells you, you can't `UPDATE` the value of an `IDENTITY`. You'll need to `CREATE` a new table, and `INSERT` the data into said new table with `IDENTITY_INSERT` enabled. Then you'll likely want to `DROP` your old table, and rename your new table.

Comment: With foreign key constraints there is a lot to consider. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049210/adding-an-identity-to-an-existing-column. Plus there is no count of the rows involved. Under these circumstances will need to go through with a side table, replace the foreign key constraints, drop the old table and (sp_)rename the new table to old table. I am afraid this is tedious.

Answer (score 1):

=NOT A REAL ANSWER TO THE ORIGINAL QUESTION, see comment=

You can not update a column which in itself is your join criteria. This just ain't work.

The safest way to keep the identity column intact is to delete rows from Table B in Table A first.
Then just insert from Table B into Table A with IDENTITY_INSERT ON.
Also this assumes there is a 1:1 relationship between the rows common to Table A and Table B. A 1:0-1 relationship between Table A and B means you need to capture ID from Table B in Table A as a foreign key relationship and separate column instead if this can lead to NULL results in Table A.

So in a nutshell (pseudo code) with assumption of 1:1 relationship between the rows:

```
DELETE FROM Table A WHERE Key EXISTS IN (SELECT Key FROM Table B)
;
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Table A ON
;
INSERT INTO Table A
(  id_column, [other_columns [, othercolumns] ] )
SELECT
  id_column, [other_columns [, othercolumns] ]
FROM Table B
;
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Table A OFF
;
```

Comment: Looks good on the first sigh, but DELETE wont work since I have many FK pointing to TableA.