# INPUT VALUE depending on the table rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to input a new row in a table with the following design

```
CREATE TABLE DMZ
(
DDM date NOT NULL,
NDM int NOT NULL,
PR int NOT NULL
CONSTRAINT PK_DMZ PRIMARY KEY(NDM)
);
```

PR can only be 1, or 2, which I defined as a constraint.(1 if this document is for income, and 2 if this document is a consumption. DM is a document number (actually Id in my case).

```
ALTER TABLE DMZ
ADD CONSTRAINT PR CHECK (PR IN (1,2));
```

I filled it with some handwritten data

```
INSERT INTO DMZ VALUES('2014.01.04', 20, 1);
INSERT INTO DMZ VALUES('2014.01.04', 21, 1);
INSERT INTO DMZ VALUES('2014.01.04', 22, 2);
```

There are two rows, where PR = 1, and only one where PR = 2. I want to write a script to INSERT a new row like this

```
INSERT INTO DMZ(DDM, PR) VALUES(GETDATE(), X)
```

Where X, I want to have something like "count rows where PR = 1 and rows where PR = 2, and if there more rows where PR = 1, use PR = 2 in newly inserted row, and if there are more rows where PR = 2, use PR = 1.
P.S.: That is a recreation of my deleted answer, hope now it's clear. To those who asked, why am I doing such a nonsence - it is a part of a list of tasks I HAVE to perform. I tried to do it, but I don't know how to perform this part with PR.
EDIT: I managed to write what I needed, but I am getting the following error ""Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery."

```
INSERT INTO DMZ(ddm, pr)
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN (COUNT(CASE WHEN PR = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)> COUNT(CASE WHEN PR = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) THEN 1 ELSE 2 END) AS pr, GETDATE() as ddm
FROM DMZ
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing a `INSERT` `SELECT` statement with a `CASE` statement to check your `PR` counts using `SUM` and `CASE` in a subquery:

```
INSERT INTO DMZ (a.DDM, a.NDM, a.PR)
SELECT GETDATE() AS DOM,
       a.NDM AS NDM, 
       CASE WHEN a.PR_1_Count > a.PR_2_Count 
        THEN 2
        ELSE 1
       END AS PR
FROM (SELECT
        MAX(NDM) + 1 AS NDM,
        SUM(CASE WHEN PR = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS PR_1_Count, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN PR = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS PR_2_Count
       FROM DMZ) a
```

Fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/FegL3Mx_).

**Note:** If you want an actual count to be inserted, remove your `CONSTRAINT` for the PR check and change the `CASE` statement from `THEN 2` to `THEN PR_2_Count` and `THEN 1` to `THEN PR_1_Count`.

Also, I've hardcoded a `NDM` column value in my demo because you're column is set to `NOT NULL`, I assume you'll handle that.

**Update:** Per your comment below, I've updated the syntax to include `MAX(NDM) + 1`. I would, however, suggest adding a new `NDM` `IDENTITY` column to replace your current `NDM` column so that it will generate your `PK` for you vs. generating the value yourself (see the attached Fiddle for an example of this). Read more about `IDENTITY` columns [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-ver16) and how to do it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049210/adding-an-identity-to-an-existing-column).

> Identity columns can be used for generating key values. The identity
> property on a column guarantees the following:
>
> Each new value is generated based on the current seed & increment.
>
> Each new value for a particular transaction is different from other
> concurrent transactions on the table.
>
> The identity property on a column does not guarantee the following:
>
> Uniqueness of the value - Uniqueness must be enforced by using a
> PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE constraint or UNIQUE index.

Comment: I have one more question, I tried to add an extra select after your code to fill the NDM with the highest + 1 instead of 27(I removed 27 as NDM). My select is 
(SELECT (MAX(NDM) + 1) as NDM
FROM DMZ)
But it keep saying, that "statement contains fewer items than the insert list". Could you, please, help me with this one so I won't create an addition question topic.

Comment: @Palamar66 I've updated my answer for you to include this. Please consider using an `IDENTITY` column going forward (see my updated note and fiddle).