# When appending a table using Import Wizard in SSMS, how can I have the ID auto increment?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I'm using the Import Wizard to import data from an Excel file into an existing table.

Currently, I have to take the largest ID from the spreadsheet, copy it, refresh the sheet, paste that value + 1 into the first empty cell in the ID column, + 1 in the next row, then auto fill it all the way down the sheet.

Then I save it and use the import wizard in SSMS to import that data into the table.

When I looked up how to have auto increment, it said to hit "edit SQL" after selecting "Edit Mappings" but that option is greyed out for me since I'm appending I'm assuming.

I haven't been able to find a way that allows auto increment, which would drastically cut down the time it takes to do all this. I can't copy/paste because the file has too many rows and causes the server to crash.

[Edit SQL greyed out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwzD2.png)

I tried leaving the ID column blank and selected "enable identity insert" and that would work, but I just got an error that the action couldn't be executed.

Comment: If the column is defined as an `IDENTITY` then just *don't insert* the ID.

Comment: @ThomA it's defined as a Primary Key, will that do the same thing?

Comment: That's something entirely different.

Comment: Ok, so is there a solution to this or do I just have to keep doing what I'm doing currently?

Comment: If you want an auto incrementing column, then use an `IDENTITY`. As, however, you've already created the table, you may want to use a `SEQUENCE` as the `DEFAULT` value now, as you can't `ALTER` a column to be an `IDENTITY`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding an identity to an existing column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049210/adding-an-identity-to-an-existing-column)

Comment: You can drop your ID column and add it back as identity. Something like: `ALTER TABLE X DROP COLUMN ID; ALTER TABLE X ADD ID INT IDENTITY` You might need to drop the PK first though :) it's a mess

Comment: You may want to reconsider those `float` data types and use `decimal` instead.