# How to change value of primary key and update foreign key in the same time

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, primary-key

I have a record in table with wrong primary key. I want change it to  correct value, but this value is used in many other tables.

Is there any simple way to update primary key and foreign key at the same tim?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the foreign keys are set to cascade changes then the value should change automatically.

Comment: I get: Cannot update identity column 'Id'.query is UPDATE [TableA]
   SET Id= 8
 WHERE Id= 9

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/751522/how-to-change-identity-column-values-programmatically

Comment: @user278618: you **cannot** update an existing `IDENTITY` value - there is no way to do this.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that your foreign key relationships have ON UPDATE CASCADE specified, and the foreign key will automatically update to match the primary key.

From Books Online:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174123%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx

> ON UPDATE {CASCADE | NO ACTION | SET
>   DEFAULT | SET NULL}
>
> Specifies what action happens to a row in the table that is created when
>   that row has a referential
>   relationship, and the referenced row
>   is updated in the parent table. The
>   default is NO ACTION. See the
>   "Remarks" section later in this topic
>   for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Updating a primary key does not update related foreign keys, it only deletes the related records on other tables as Sql Server treats update as delete and insert. This is Sql Server 2000, not sure later versions. Using "on cascading update on cascading delete", the cascading effects of the "delete and insert:aka update", deletes the related records on other tables.

Answer (score 0):

If You want to update the foreign key when the primary key is changed , we can use 'ON UPDATE CASCADE' command on Foreign Key References .

```
Create table Customer(
  customer_id int primary key ,
  customer_name varchar(30),
  customer_address varchar(50),
  Foreign Key (salesman_id) References Salesman(salesman_id)
  ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
```

Here the Foreign key 'salesman_id' in 'Customer' table references Primary Key 'salesman_id' in 'Salesman' table. As We Used 'ON UPDATE CASCADE' in the foreign key references , the changes made for the salesman_id in the 'Salesman' table will also get reflected in the customer tables 'salesman_id' Field .

So, We Use 'ON UPDATE CASCADE' To Automatically Update the Foreign Key Values in  the related table when the value of primary key is changed in the reference Table