# changing the name of the primary key

Tags: mysql, kohana, workbench

I have 20 tables in my MySQL database. I read the Kohana documentation and learned that in order for ORM to work properly, the primary key of tables should be named 'id'.

I have created my tables before knowing this requirement and primary key are  named in the format ID (eg:- UsersID).  I believe, if i change the name of the primary keys then i have to reset all the references(FK) manually which is a herculean task.

I am using Workbench and is there any option available to automtically update references(FK) once i change the name of the primary key.

Comment: if i understand correctly, do you wants to rename pkey in mysql

Comment: Might be this question can solve your problem.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6388063/how-to-change-value-of-primary-key-and-update-foreign-key-in-the-same-time.

Answer (score 0):

*if I understand correctly, do you want like following as:*

*it's no different than altering any other column --*

```
ALTER TABLE `pkey` CHANGE `keyfield` `keyfield2` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
```

*This changes the column `keyfield` in table `pkey` to be called `keyfield2` -- you have to supply the definition afterwards, as usual.*

Answer (score 0):

You can also configure ORM to use a field other that `id` as the primary key in the model:

```
protected $_primary_key = 'your_id';
```

The field used must be indexed and unique. ([documented here](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/orm/models#changing-the-primary-key))

This is often helpful when using Kohana/ORM with existing databases.