# How can I insert identity manually?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
CREATE TABLE masterTbl (
id INT IDENTITY(1,1) CONSTRAINT pk_id PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO masterTbl VALUES ('ABC', 'XYZ','PQR')
```

Now

```
Select * FROM masterTbl
```

Result:

```
id  | name
---------------------
1 |  ABC
2 |  XYZ
3 |  PQR

DELETE FROM masterTbl WHERE id=1
```

Now

```
Select * FROM masterTbl
```

Result:

```
id |  name
---------------------
2 |  XYZ
3 |  PQR
```

Now I want to run:

```
INSERT INTO masterTbl (id, name) VALUES (1, 'MNO')
```

How is this possible?

Comment: Related (or duplicate) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/751522/how-to-change-identity-column-values-programmatically

Answer (score 72, accepted):

In it's simplest form, you need to temporarily allow the insertion of identity values

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT masterTbl ON
INSERT INTO masterTbl (id, name) VALUES (1, 'MNO')
SET IDENTITY_INSERT masterTbl OFF
```

Comment: Setting identiy on or off, SQL spews the the same ambiguous error: "An explicit value for the identity column in table 'X' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON"

Comment: @alejandrob - I would suggest that with 60 upvotes (and I'm assuming you're my first downvote on this answer) that my example is not the problem... check you've actually listed the correct column(s)

Comment: What happens to the identity sequence after doing this? Is it broken or does SQL server handle this behind the scenes so you don't have to reseed the sequence?

Comment: @Morgeth888 - good question. If the value being inserted is **above** the current identity then the identity will increased to that new value.  However, if the value being inserted is **below or equal** the current identity then the identity will remain as is

Answer (score 12):

Yes you can set identity fields manually executing

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT masterTbl ON
```

then insert your data

```
INSERT INTO masterTbl (id, name) VALUES (1, 'MNO') 
......
```

and remember to call

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT masterTbl OFF
```

to reenable the correct functionality

Answer (score 5):

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT masterTbl ON
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 1):

It is possible performing the following steps:

I. Enable identity insert, which will DISABLE SQL Server from automatically inserting values in the table's identity column:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON
```

II. Perform your "manual" insert operation, SPECIFYING all the affected column names:

```
INSERT INTO masterTbl (id, name)
VALUES (1, 'ABC',
        2, 'XYZ',
        4, 'PQR')
```

- If you skip listing the column names, SQL Server will popup an error message.

III. When you're done, reenable the auto identity value insertion by disabling the manual insert feature of earlier:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT OFF
```

IV. You're done!