# Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'TBL_AT_INOUT' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set OFF

Tags: sql-server

```
Insert into HWT FINAL. DO. TBL_AT_INOUT
(ID)
SELECT ID FROM TBL_AT_INOUT_20171208
WHERE ID=904017
```

Getting error while executing

Comment: Kindly stop yelling first. No one likes all caps. Why are you trying to do an insert of *only an ID value* into a table in the first place? This definitely sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: Have you tried SET IDENTITY_INSERT **ON** before the insert? As per the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql

Comment: @JacobH there are use cases for this, just do it correctly with it set to ON

Comment: Did you even google at all?   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12563522/how-can-i-insert-identity-manually

Comment: @gbn yes I tried set IDENTITY_INSERT table name on
But I got another error.

Comment: @gbn Oh sure there are use cases. But if someone doesn't know what an Identity insert is and they're *only inserting an identity column*, my hunch is that this isn't one of those use cases. Hence the XY problem.

Comment: @sahilehsan what is the other error?

Answer (score 0):

This is what you're looking for:

```
IF object_id(N'tempdb..#test_table_01', N'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #test_table_01;

go

CREATE TABLE #test_table_01
  (
       [id]     INT IDENTITY(1, 1)
       , [name] SYSNAME
  );

--
-- fail method
-------------------------------------------------
BEGIN
    BEGIN try
        INSERT INTO #test_table_01
                    ([id]
                     , [name])
        VALUES      (1,N'Lucy');
    END try
    BEGIN catch
        SELECT N'This throws an error' AS [result]
               , ERROR_MESSAGE()       AS [error_message];
    END catch;

    SELECT N'No records were inserted' AS [note]
           , [id]
           , [name]
    FROM   #test_table_01;
END;


--
-- success method
-------------------------------------------------
BEGIN
    BEGIN try
        SET IDENTITY_INSERT #test_table_01 ON;

        INSERT INTO #test_table_01
                    ([id]
                     , [name])
        VALUES      (1,N'Lucy');

        -- 
        -- REMEMBER TO SET IDENTITY_INSERT BACK OFF!!!
        SET IDENTITY_INSERT #test_table_01 OFF;
    END try
    BEGIN catch
        SELECT N'This allows the insert' AS [result]
               , ERROR_MESSAGE()         AS [error_message];
    END catch;

    SELECT N'Records were inserted as desired!' AS [note]
           , [id]
           , [name]
    FROM   #test_table_01;
END;
```

Comment: Remove the name column to make it like the original question.l does it still work?

Comment: I try to usually include test code for that reason, so you can try it yourself and use it as a prototype for building what you need. But yes, it does work. The SET IDENTITY_INSERT (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql) function is what you are looking for. Just remember to set it back off after you've inserted your values.

Comment: I'm not the OP. But I was suggesting that you make it match what OP asked, That is all.