# What is an efficient way to create records in one table that first rely on outputs from another?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a **User** table with a **ReferenceId** column, which points to a **Reference** table.  Each user needs a **ReferenceId** which has to first be generated by an INSERT into a **Reference** table.  The ReferenceId is a unique number that is different for each and every user.

User.ReferenceId = Reference.Id

**User Table**

```
+------------+----------+-------------+--+
| First Name | LastName | ReferenceId |  |
+------------+----------+-------------+--+
| Bob        | Smith    |         123 |  |
| John       | Smith    |         456 |  |
+------------+----------+-------------+--+
```

**Reference Table**

```
+-----+----------+--+
| Id  |   Type   |  |
+-----+----------+--+
| 123 | External |  |
| 456 | Internal |  |
+-----+----------+--+
```

I will need to perform an operation to create two million users. I understand that if I create one user at a time sequentially, I can use the Output keyword to capture each generated **ReferenceId**, and then use it in my INSERT statement to the **User** table.

But is it possible to use batch/bulk operations here to improve performance so that I can create all the ReferenceIds in a single query, and then map all of them to a BULK INSERT to the **User** table, so that all new users can be created with their corresponding ReferenceIds in a single Query?

Comment: You can use the `output` clause to insert as many records as you like? Its not clear from your question what the relationship is between your user and your reference. What is the generation process? Can users share a reference? Why is it stored in a separate table?

Comment: @DaleK To clarify the relationship between User and Reference: The Reference.Id column is a unique identifier and it is a foreign key in the User table, in the ReferenceId column.  Each User has a different and unique ReferenceId.  The Reference Id should be generated by the SQL Server engine upon insert, before the User record is created.  Users cannot share a reference.  The tables in my question are not the actual table of my project.  I've created these simplistic tables to show my problem, and to leave out unnecessary information.

Comment: [edit] any additional info directly into the question. And the answer IMO is to use the `output` clause.

Comment: What is the point having two separate tables to store a 1-1 relationship? Just simplify your design and store both information in the same table.

Comment: From a data modelling perspective there doesn't seem to be much point to the reference table if it's just 1-1 with the User Table. What is the unique key of the User table and how is it generated? Is it from source data or is it generated by SQL Server?

Comment: @DalhousieDuck A reference has a "type". How does one determine what type of reference to create for the user? Can a user have multiple references of different types? Are users *required* to have a reference of each type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GMB and others covered the design aspect of this; this is definitely not an ideal way of separating your data. However, to answer your question:

If the only way to capture which ReferenceID goes to which User is during the INSERT into ReferenceTable, then we either need to step in and capture this before moving on to the next ReferenceTable entry (which means doing these 1 at a time), or we manually configure this so no capture is necessary.

Best way to do this in bulk is to use a staging table. This staging table will enable you to keep a key between the two tables *en masse*. Bulk insert all your 2M users into a staging table; add a new column named referenceID;  populate this with whatever your next set of records would be, and then use this staging table to create your final records. [Force identity insert if necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12563522/how-can-i-insert-identity-manually/12563552).

```sql
-- bulk load everything into stagingTable using your preferred method

-- Create sequence to hold your new referenceID
-- Start higher than your current max referenceID to avoid overlap
create sequence myNewIDSEQ
start with 456
increment by 1;
go

-- Create column to hold new referenceID
alter table stagingTable add referenceID int;
go

-- Update referenceID with a unique value for each entry
update stagingTable set referenceID = NEXT VALUE FOR myNewIDSEQ;

-- Merge your staging table against your Reference table to create all these new users 
MERGE [referenceTable] as dest
USING stagingTable as src 
ON dest.referenceID = src.referenceID
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    INSERT  (referenceID, [type])
    VALUES (referenceID, [type]);

-- Now Merge your staging table against your User table to create those users
MERGE [userTable] as dest
USING stagingTable as src 
ON dest.referenceID = src.referenceID
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    INSERT  (referenceID, firstName, lastName)
    VALUES (referenceID, firstName, lastName);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an insert trigger to insert a reference for each user and also update the users table.

```
create trigger on_insert_add_reference on "user"
  after insert
as
  declare @ref_ids table(id int, user_id int)
  set nocount on
begin
  -- For each inserted user, insert into reference.
  -- Store the reference id and user id pair in @ref_ids.
  merge reference 
  using inserted as inserted_users
  on (1 = 0)
  when not matched then
      insert ("type") values('external')
  output inserted.id, inserted_users.id into @ref_ids;

  -- Update the just inserted users with their reference IDs.
  update "user"
  set reference_id = [@ref_ids].id
  from "user"
  join inserted on inserted.id = "user".id
  join @ref_ids on [@ref_ids].user_id = "user".id;
end
```

[Try it](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b867f9b459a7f1d0dd9fb6470972b0e5).

You'll also need a delete trigger to delete references when the user is deleted.

One problem with this approach is `users.reference_id` cannot be made `not null`. It's possible it could be rewritten as an `instead of insert` trigger.

---

Since this is a 1-to-1 relationship, it is much simpler to put the reference ID and type into users. Since it is "a unique number that is different for each and every user" it could simply be their primary key.

Comment: Question is tagged SQL Server which works quite differently.

Comment: @DaleK Boy, you weren't kidding about it being quite different!