# Cannot update identity column 'LocationID'

Tags: c#, .net, sql

I am trying to update an ID value. So if the ID is 1 the new value is 2 it should replace the old ID with the new.

Back end:

```
     public static void UpdateLocation( int locationID, SqlConnection connection,                SqlTransaction transaction )
    {
        StringBuilder sqlString = new StringBuilder();
        SqlCommand command;

        sqlString.Append( "UPDATE [Location] SET " );
        sqlString.Append( "description = @description " );
        sqlString.Append( "WHERE locationID = @locationID " );
        command = new SqlCommand( sqlString.ToString(), connection );
        if( ( transaction != null ) ) command.Transaction = transaction;

        command.Parameters.Add( "@locationID", SqlDbType.Int ).Value = locationID;
       command.Parameters.Add( "@description", SqlDbType.VarChar ).Value = description;
        int rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        if( !( rowsAffected == 1 ) )
        {
            throw new Exception( "An error has occurred while updating UpdateMedicationDispenseStatus." );
        }
    }
```

Front End:

```
      private void btnFromLocation_Click( object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e )
     {
         if( !( ( Locations )cmbLocationDescriptionList.SelectedItem == ( Locations )cmbDescriptionListTo.SelectedItem ) )
         {


             for( int i = 0; i < lstMedicationForCurrentLocation.SelectedItems.Count; i++ )
    {
                 location = (Locations)cmbDescriptionListTo.SelectedItem;
        LocationData.UpdateLocation( location.LocationID );
```

**EDIT** I have added a parameter to the SQL Query but still doesnt Update

Comment: You can't (well, shouldn't be able to) change the value of a primary key. If you need a changeable identifier, you should add a new one to the table. May I ask why you're trying to change it in the first place?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/751522/how-to-change-identity-column-values-programmatically

Comment: If it's marked as an identity column in the database, why would you be updating it at all? If this column has some other use than a unique identifier as sorts, remove the identity spec. If you just wanted to create new rows with a specific ID, then you can turn `IDENTITY_INSERT` for this table on and off around your query.

Comment: Are you sure `rowsAffected == 1` after the Update? I mean your `WHERE` clause may match more than 1 because of your fault in data table design.

Comment: Please look at the EDIT. Thanks

Comment: Your query sets LocationID to the same value it already has, so why not not just set `Description` and leave LocationID unchanged?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Appologies forgot the delete the LocationID. I have now removed it. Stil not updating the database

Comment: @Mark Hm, but you should not get the same error at least...?

Comment: In general relational theory (if I can be forgiven for ragging on MS for a moment) primary keys aren't read-only, they're just unique and non-nullable. You certainly should be able to change them.  Referencing foreign keys should have an "on update cascade" option. Auto-incrementing should be done by setting the default to the result of an expression that may involve a function call, .eg the next value of a sequence. SQL Server takes it's que from MS Access where these "identity" fields are concerned. It is neither standard nor robust, and it's the cause of a whole lot of pain and suffering.

Answer (score 6):

**The below workaround may not be  preferable but At least from knowledge perspective this may be helpful to you.**

Some workaround are there if you want to set Identity column (LocationID)  value yourself rather then let do the Sql server.

```
set identity_insert Table_Name ON
```

Then delete your row and reinsert it with different identity. Please note that you still cannot update the same row to a new Identity. This will allow insert statements to specify Identity column values.

Once you have done the insert with new identity value , turn `identity_insert` off

```
set identity_insert Table_Name OFF
```

Since you are doing updates programmatically, you can have the Values of all Columns, and probably insert a new row with same values for all columns except the Identity Value which will be of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

LocationID is an automatically generated id then. You should change in database. You should set identity to no.

Comment: Look at the EDIT. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if Identity_insert is enabled in your SQL db , else do it as below before your update statement.

set identity_insert YourTable ON .
Then delete your row and reinsert it with different identity.

Once you have done the insert don't forget to turn identity_insert off

set identity_insert YourTable OFF.