# Disallow update on column for all users, in all circumstaces in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to disallow updates by all users on a column? Consider the following table:

```
Create table [MyTable]
(
    [Id] int not null identity primary key,
    [Description] varchar(30) not null,
    [Length] int not null
)
```

In order to maintain my system's integrity, I need the `[Length]` column to not be allowed to change after a record is inserted.

Here are a couple of options I have explored:

1. using a trigger:

   ```
   create trigger [Trigger_MyTable] on [MyTable]
   for update
   as
   begin
       if UPDATE([Length])
       begin
            RAISERROR('Change not allowed.', 16, 1)
            Rollback Transaction
       end
   end
   ```
2. using `DENY UPDATE` :

   ```
   DENY UPDATE ON [MyTable]([Length]) TO [User1]
   ```

The reason I'm disinclined to use the trigger is when working with tables with triggers in the past I have experienced a significant performance declines when performing update statements. (E.G. updating 20,000 rows in table took 4-5 minutes with `instead of update` trigger, < 1 second after dropping trigger. `For update` might be faster, have not tested.)

The `DENY UPDATE` feature would by handy but is there a way to have it apply to ALL users (including admin/owner users)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most reliable way of preventing **accidental** updates is the trigger.

Permissions aren't checked for people in the sysadmin role or the database owner so the `deny` won't work, these people can always disable the trigger though so it doesn't add any more security.

If you are on 2012+ there is one more theoretical possibility.

`IDENTITY` columns are immutable and cannot be updated so you could replace your existing identity with a sequence, make the length column an `IDENTITY` and ensure all your inserts `SET IDENTITY_INSERT` on to insert the explicit values.

This might be confusing to other developers though and still wouldn't prevent an update being simulated by a `DELETE...INSERT` pair.

Comment: Values in identity columns can be updated, see `SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON|OFF`. Triggers seem the best way to go, but note that Owners and Admins can still drop or disable them.

Comment: @PhilipKelley Nope, `identity_insert` only allows you to insert them, not update them. Someone with appropriate permissions could use [this approach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/751522/how-to-change-identity-column-values-programmatically/17249583#17249583) but simply deleting and inserting would be easier.